# python numpy euclidean distance calculation between matrices of row vectors

Tags: python, vector, numpy, scipy, euclidean-distance

I am new to Numpy and I would like to ask you how to calculate euclidean distance between points stored in a vector.

Let's assume that we have a numpy.array each row is a vector and a single numpy.array. I would like to know if it is possible to calculate the euclidean distance between all the points and this single point and store them in one numpy.array.

Here is an interface:

```
points #2d list of row-vectors
singlePoint #one row-vector

listOfDistances= procedure( points,singlePoint)
```

Can we have something like this?
Or is it possible to have one command to have the single point as a list of other points and at the end we get a matrix of distances?

Thanks

Comment: Although you want to calculate the distance between a point and a set of points, I think scipy.spatial.distance.cdist still works. You have 2 collections, one of which have only 1 element.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871536/euclidean-distance-between-points-in-two-different-numpy-arrays-not-within

Comment: @JimRaynor +1 Was exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

While you can use vectorize, @Karl's approach will be rather slow with numpy arrays.

The easier approach is to just do `np.hypot(*(points - single_point).T)`. (The transpose assumes that points is a Nx2 array, rather than a 2xN. If it's 2xN, you don't need the `.T`.

However this is a bit unreadable, so you write it out more explictly like this (using some canned example data...):

```
import numpy as np
single_point = [3, 4]
points = np.arange(20).reshape((10,2))

dist = (points - single_point)**2
dist = np.sum(dist, axis=1)
dist = np.sqrt(dist)
```

Comment: Even though this does the job, you'd better use existing functions like
np.linalg.norm(x - y, axis=1) or distance.euclidean or cdist.

Comment: To expand on @VadimKirilchuk's comment in the context of the example above: `np.linalg.norm(points - single_point, axis=1)`

Answer (score 34):

To get the distance you can use the norm method of the linalg module in numpy:

```
np.linalg.norm(x - y)
```

Comment: This should be the right answer, you can also play with axis parameter (depends on what you want to do)
X is you N*2 vector
y is your point

Answer (score 7):

```
import numpy as np
def distance(v1, v2):
    return np.sqrt(np.sum((v1 - v2) ** 2))
```

Comment: That's the same as the above but in one line

Answer (score 3):

To apply a function to each element of a numpy array, try [numpy.vectorize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html).

To do the actual calculation, we need the square root of the sum of squares of differences (whew!) between pairs of coordinates in the two vectors.

We can use `zip` to pair the coordinates, and `sum` with a comprehension to sum up the results. That looks like:

```
sum((x - y) ** 2 for (x, y) in zip(singlePoint, pointFromArray)) ** 0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
single_point = [3, 4]
points = np.arange(20).reshape((10,2))   
distance = euclid_dist(single_point,points)

def euclid_dist(t1, t2):
    return np.sqrt(((t1-t2)**2).sum(axis = 1))
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.