# Identifying points with the smallest Euclidean distance

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, nearest-neighbor, euclidean-distance

I have a collection of n dimensional points and I want to find which 2 are the closest. The best I could come up for 2 dimensions is:

```
from numpy import *
myArr = array( [[1, 2],
                [3, 4],
                [5, 6],
                [7, 8]] )

n = myArr.shape[0]
cross = [[sum( ( myArr[i] - myArr[j] ) ** 2 ), i, j]
         for i in xrange( n )
         for j in xrange( n )
         if i != j
         ]

print min( cross )
```

which gives

```
[8, 0, 1]
```

But this is too slow for large arrays. What kind of optimisation can I apply to it?

RELATED:

---

[Euclidean distance between points in two different Numpy arrays, not within](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1871536/188368)

Comment: @Ηλίας: Roughly how many points do you have? Please note that it's  possible to have a set more than 2 points (even all the points) with the same distances (but inaccurate computations may not reflect this, so eventually you need to be able to set a threshold trh where distance differences below trh are considered equal). You are not interested to find out closest point to a given one?

Comment: @eat It is a hierarchy cluster that I am building, and I need to find the two closest centroids. Normally less than a thousand points, but I need to see how much it can scale. Rounding errors, won't be that important in my case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist(myArr)`.  This will give you a condensed distance matrix.  You can use `argmin` on it and find the index of the smallest value.  This can be converted into the pair information.

Comment: What is the easiest way to get those coordinates from that single integer?

Comment: @Ηλίας You can use `np.unravel_index(np.argmin(distances), distances.shape)` if *distances* contains the result of the *pdist* call above.

Comment: It gives me a stomachache to use this method for finding closest pairs in O(N^2) time, because the divide-and-conquer O(N log N) solution was literally the first algorithm I learned in my algorithms class in school.  But this is just so much easier to implement and it works fine for a small enough set.

Answer (score 9):

There's a whole Wikipedia page on just this problem, see:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points

Executive summary:  you can achieve O(n log n) with a recursive divide and conquer algorithm (outlined on the Wiki page, above).

Comment: Neat! I'm glad I hit refresh before writing: "Obviously the complexity is O(n^2)" ;o)

Comment: Great. If the points are to be added successively, and the minimum distance pair is to be updated, then maintaining a Delaunay triangulation structure is efficient.

Answer (score 6):

You could take advantage of the latest version of SciPy's (v0.9) Delaunay triangulation tools.  You can be sure that the closest two points will be an edge of a simplex in the triangulation, which is a much smaller subset of pairs than doing every combination.

Here's the code (updated for general N-D):

```
import numpy
from scipy import spatial

def closest_pts(pts):
    # set up the triangluataion
    # let Delaunay do the heavy lifting
    mesh = spatial.Delaunay(pts)

    # TODO: eliminate reduncant edges (numpy.unique?)
    edges = numpy.vstack((mesh.vertices[:,:dim], mesh.vertices[:,-dim:]))

    # the rest is easy
    x = mesh.points[edges[:,0]]
    y = mesh.points[edges[:,1]]

    dists = numpy.sum((x-y)**2, 1)
    idx = numpy.argmin(dists)

    return edges[idx]
    #print 'distance: ', dists[idx]
    #print 'coords:\n', pts[closest_verts]

dim = 3
N = 1000*dim
pts = numpy.random.random(N).reshape(N/dim, dim)
```

Seems closely O(n):

[image]

Comment: May actually work in 2D. Have you made any timings? However this approach fails miserable in higher dim. Thanks

Comment: @eat:  why do you say it "fails miserably"?  3D is 4-5X slower than the same N in 2D.  But any approach (except for the naive brute approach) is going to see slowdowns with D.

Comment: Well, it's kind of pointless to try to do Delaunay triangulation in 123D! So this won't solve OP's question (unless his nD is 2 or 3). Don't get me wrong, I'm actually very happy that `scipy` is able to perform Delaunay triangulation so fast. Please make some timings with `pdist` for n= 2...123, you'll see. Thanks

Comment: @eat:  I missed the fact that the OP wanted a general N-D solution, I was under the impression it was strictly 2D.  I'm a little "bridge-and-tunnel" and sometimes consider 3D not only as "high dimensional", but the highest!

Answer (score 2):

There is a scipy function `pdist` that will get you the pairwise distances between points in an array in a fairly efficient manner:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html

that outputs the N*(N-1)/2 unique pairs (since r_ij == r_ji). You can then search on the minimum value and avoid the whole loop mess in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could proceed along these lines:

```
In []: from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist as pd, squareform as sf
In []: m= 1234
In []: n= 123
In []: p= randn(m, n)
In []: d= sf(pd(p))
In []: a= arange(m)
In []: d[a, a]= d.max()
In []: where(d< d.min()+ 1e-9)
Out[]: (array([701, 730]), array([730, 701]))
```

With substantially more points you need to be able to somehow utilize the hierarchical structure of your clustering.

Answer (score 0):

How fast is it compared to just doing a nested loop and keeping track of the shortest pair? I think creating a huge cross array is what might be hurting you. Even O(n^2) is still pretty quick if you're only doing 2 dimensional points.

Comment: It helps, but quickly degenerates for large matrices

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is OK for small datasets, but its execution time scales as `n**2`. However, as pointed out by @payne, an optimal solution can achieve `n*log(n)` computation time scaling.

This optial solution can be obtained using [sklearn.neighbors.BallTree](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html) as follows.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree as tree

n = 10
dim = 2
xy = np.random.uniform(size=[n, dim])

# This solution is optimal when xy is very large
res = tree(xy)
dist, ids = res.query(xy, 2)
mindist = dist[:, 1]  # second nearest neighbour
minid = np.argmin(mindist)

plt.plot(*xy.T, 'o')
plt.plot(*xy[ids[minid]].T, '-o')
```

This procedure scales well for very large sets of `xy` values and even for large dimensions `dim` (altough the example illustrates the case `dim=2`). The resulting output looks like this

[image: The nearest pair of points is connected by an orange line]

An identical solution can be obtained using [scipy.spatial.cKDTree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html), by replacing the `sklearn` import with the following Scipy one. Note however that `cKDTree`, unlike `BallTree`, does not scale well for high dimensions

```
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree as tree
```