# euclidean distance between values in a array - result ordered asc in new array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, euclidean-distance

I'm looking for a fast way to compute euclidean distance of all values in a array. The Result should be in a new array ordered ascending with the two used "partners" for calculation.

eg:

```
a = [[2,4,5],[3,2,1],[5,7,2]]
```

res = euclidean distance(a) ordered ascending with

format: `[result, value A, value B]`  (result is the eu.dist. between value A and value B in array a)

e.g: (not calculated)

```
res = [[4, 0, 1],[6, 0, 2], [9, 1, 2]]
```

thin i will calculate the eu.dist in this way

```
def euclidean(a, b):
    dist = numpy.linalg.norm(a-b)
    return dist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `itertools.combinations` function should work to get you the various pairs of elements, then you just need to find the distance and sort them:

```
distances = [[euclidean(points[a], points[b]), a, b]
             for a, b in itertools.combinations(range(len(points)), 2)]
distances.sort() # distance is already first element, so no key function required
```

Now, with `numpy` values this may not be the most efficient way to go, but it works.

Comment: works fine thanks 2 both! Praveen method = 0.00520396232605
blckknght method = 0.00202894210815

Answer (score 2):

Try using `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`, as given in the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871536/euclidean-distance-between-points-in-two-different-numpy-arrays-not-within) question. Both inputs would be your `a` array. The only thing is that you won't get the exact format you're looking for - you'll get a matrix with the (i,j) element giving you the required distance instead. Hope this helps.

Comment: I think `pdist` might be better than `cdist` when you just have a single list of inputs points. Alas, I don't have `scipy` installed on this system to test it out myself.

Comment: @Blckknght `pdist` will be sightly over twice as fast as `cdist` as it only has to calculate the upper triangular portion of the `cdist` array.