# Finding squared distances beteen n points to m points in numpy

Tags: python, performance, numpy, euclidean-distance

I have 2 numpy arrays (say `X` and `Y`) which each row represents a point vector.
I would like to find the squared euclidean distances (will call this 'dist') between each point in X to each point in Y.
I would like the output to be a matrix D where `D(i,j)` is `dist(X(i) , Y(j))`.

I have the following python code based on : http://nonconditional.com/2014/04/on-the-trick-for-computing-the-squared-euclidian-distances-between-two-sets-of-vectors/

```
def get_sq_distances(X, Y):
    a = np.sum(np.square(X),axis=1,keepdims=1)
    b = np.ones((1,Y.shape[0]))
    c = a.dot(b)
    a = np.ones((X.shape[0],1))
    b = np.sum(np.square(Y),axis=1,keepdims=1).T
    c += a.dot(b)
    c -= 2*X.dot(Y.T)
    return c
```

I'm trying to avoid loops (should I?) and to use matrix multiplication in order to do a fast computation.

But I have the problem with "Memory Error" on large arrays. Maybe there is a better way to do this?

Comment: @cel thats only between 2 points

Comment: @cel that's nice but its between all points in one matrix.. I have two matrices.
Also, distance between points from the same matrix is not necessary for me

Comment: You can use cel's info if you concatenate X and Y, although that will not be efficient since you will be computing X-to-X and Y-to-Y distances along the way.

Comment: Almost an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1871536/1461210 (albeit for squared euclidean distance)

Comment: I cleaned up my attempts. They were not really helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Scipy has the [`cdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.cdist) function that does exactly what you want:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
distance.cdist(X, Y, 'sqeuclidean')
```

The docs linked above have some good examples.

Comment: `'sqeuclidean'` actually.

Comment: Good call to both. Fixed.

Comment: Does it use matrix multiplication at background? @AdamAcosta

Comment: @member555 indeed it does use matrix multiplication using `np.dot` as seen in the [source code here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/a9fb36bc44bad4bbd2c1a41cb43c6f10925b38ae/scipy/spatial/distance.py#L228).

Answer (score 1):

subtract lists, then square the list, then do sum.

```
import numpy as np
def get_sq_distances(a,b):
    return np.sum(np.square(np.subtract(a,b)))
print(get_sq_distances([5,7,9],[4,5,6]))
```