# Calculate Euclidean distance between two python arrays

Tags: python, list, numpy, euclidean-distance, array-broadcasting

I want to write a function to calculate the Euclidean distance between coordinates in `list_a` to each of the coordinates in `list_b`, and produce an array of distances of dimension `a` rows by `b` columns (where `a` is the number of coordinates in `list_a` and `b` is the number of coordinates in `list_b`.

NB: I do not want to use any libraries other than numpy, for simplicity.

```
list_a = np.array([[0,1], [2,2], [5,4], [3,6], [4,2]])
list_b = np.array([[0,1],[5,4]])
```

Running the function would generate:

```
>>> np.array([[0., 5.830951894845301],
              [2.236, 3.605551275463989],
              [5.830951894845301, 0.],
              [5.830951894845301, 2.8284271247461903],
              [4.123105625617661, 2.23606797749979]])
```

I have been trying to run the below

```
def run_euc(list_a,list_b):
    euc_1 = [np.subtract(list_a, list_b)]
    euc_2 = sum(sum([i**2 for i in euc_1]))
    return np.sqrt(euc_2)
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,2) (2,2)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please share the entire error message. What's `euc_1 = [np.subtract(list_a, list_b)]` for?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Minimum Euclidean distance between points in two different Numpy arrays, not within](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871536/minimum-euclidean-distance-between-points-in-two-different-numpy-arrays-not-wit)

Comment: How are you expecting your code to provide a Euclidean distance?  You have one vector of five points, and another vector of two points.  You can't subtract vectors of different lengths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, you can just use `np.linalg.norm` to compute the Euclidean distance. Your bug is due to np.subtract is expecting the two inputs are of the same length.

```
import numpy as np

list_a = np.array([[0,1], [2,2], [5,4], [3,6], [4,2]])
list_b = np.array([[0,1],[5,4]])

def run_euc(list_a,list_b):
    return np.array([[ np.linalg.norm(i-j) for j in list_b] for i in list_a])

print(run_euc(list_a, list_b))
```

The code produces:

```
[[0.         5.83095189]
 [2.23606798 3.60555128]
 [5.83095189 0.        ]
 [5.83095189 2.82842712]
 [4.12310563 2.23606798]]
```

Comment: I really don't seem to understand the syntax for applying calculations across different sized arrays. Do you have a good online resource I could use? Trying to replicate your list comprehension across another similar problem with different array shapes and getting errors. Thank you

Comment: when I first started writing list comprehension, I would write the for loops explicitly, then as a practice, I would write them in one line, the outest most for loop remains the outer for loop.

Comment: Thank you for this; but is there any way to do this without using loops? As far as I understand looping over array is computationally taxing

Comment: what about the scipy solution provided by the other answer

Answer (score 3):

I wonder what is stopping you from using Scipy. Since you are anyway using numpy, perhaps you can try using Scipy, which is not so heavy.

***Why?***
It has many mathematical functions with efficient implementations to make good use of your computing power.

With that in mind, here is a **[distance_matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance_matrix.html)** function exactly for the purpose you've mentioned.

Concretely, it takes your list_a (m x k matrix) and list_b (n x k matrix) and outputs m x n matrix with p-norm (p=2 for euclidean) distance between each pair of points across the two matrices.

```
from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix
distances = distance_matrix(list_a, list_b)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this works

```
  import numpy as np
  def distance(x,y):
      x=np.array(x)
      y=np.array(y)
      p=np.sum((x-y)**2)
      d=np.sqrt(p)
      return d
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `scipy`, you could compute distance between each pair as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import distance
list_a = np.array([[0,1], [2,2], [5,4], [3,6], [4,2]])
list_b = np.array([[0,1],[5,4]])
dist = distance.cdist(list_a, list_b, 'euclidean')
print(dist)
```

Result:

```
array([[0.        , 5.83095189],
       [2.23606798, 3.60555128],
       [5.83095189, 0.        ],
       [5.83095189, 2.82842712],
       [4.12310563, 2.23606798]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answers the question but this is a repeat of;
[Minimum Euclidean distance between points in two different Numpy arrays, not within](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871536/minimum-euclidean-distance-between-points-in-two-different-numpy-arrays-not-wit)

```
# Import package
import numpy as np

# Define unequal matrices
xy1 = np.array([[0,1], [2,2], [5,4], [3,6], [4,2]])
xy2 = np.array([[0,1],[5,4]])

P = np.add.outer(np.sum(xy1**2, axis=1), np.sum(xy2**2, axis=1))
N = np.dot(xy1, xy2.T)
dists = np.sqrt(P - 2*N)
print(dists)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can do this is:

```
np.array(
[np.sqrt((list_a[:,1]-list_b[i,1])**2+(list_a[:,0]-list_b[i,0])**2) for i in range(len(list_b))]
).T
```

Output:

```
array([[0.        , 5.83095189],
       [2.23606798, 3.60555128],
       [5.83095189, 0.        ],
       [5.83095189, 2.82842712],
       [4.12310563, 2.23606798]])
```

This code can be written in much more simpler and efficient way,so if you find anything that could be improved in the code,please let me know in the comment.