# create a batch ( list of length 20 each) from a given list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of dictionaries. The key is item_cd and the value is location_coordinates. I would like to find the euclidian distance of these locations and create a batch of 20 based on the proximity of their locations.

### input that I want to use

```
 [{5036885850: [92.0, 88.73]}, {5036885955: [90.0, 61.73]}, 
 {5036885984: [86.0, 73.03]}, {5036885998: [102.0, 77.54]}, 
 {5036885851: [93.0, 88.0]}, {5036885956: [91.0, 66.73]}, {5036885984: [87.0, 70.0]},
 {5036885998: [101.0, 70.54]},{5036885812: [45.0, 88.73]}, {5036885955: [76.0, 60.73]},
 {5036885911: [83.0, 74.03]}, {5036885910: [108.0, 77.54]},
 {5036885850: [89.0, 76.73]},
 {5036885800: [80.0, 69.45]},
 {50368854801: [86.0, 69.50]},
 {5036885802: [102.0, 77.54]},
 {5036885809: [92.5, 85.0]},
 {5036885803: [91.5, 65.73]},
 {5036885850: [78.0, 76.73]},
 {5036885800: [77.0, 69.45]},
 {50368854801: [85.0, 69.50]},
 {5036885802: [101.50, 89.23]},
 {5036885809: [100.5, 84.84]},
 {5036885803: [100.67, 64.23]},
]
```

### Steps

#### Input used to explain the steps  is :

`[{5036885850: [92.0, 88.73]}, {5036885955: [90.0, 61.73]}, {5036885984: [86.0, 73.03]}, {5036885998: [102.0, 77.54]}]`

1. The initial distance will be calculated from the origin i.e. (0,0).
   The closest item will be added to a separate list suppose it is {5036885955: [90.0, 61.73]} in this case.
2. Now I would like to find the closest order from the centroid of the previous orders. In this case, the centroid will be [90.0, 61.73] of order {5036885955: [90.0, 61.73]} as there is only one coordinate at the moment. The next closest order from the centroid of the previous order will be {5036885984: [86.0, 73.03]}
3. I would like to repeat the above steps until the list is empty and create batches of 20 orders each. Here the length of the list is 24. So there can be two batches.
4. after one batch (list)  is created the distance will be again calculated from (0,0) from the remaining orders from the order list

`output: (in this format)`

```
[{5036885955: [90.0, 61.73]}, {5036885984: [86.0, 73.03]}, {5036885998: [102.0, 77.54]}, {5036885850: [92.0, 88.73]}]
```

What I have tried with some help on StackOverflow:

```
import numpy as np

def calcualate_centroid(lst):
    arr = np.array(lst)
    length = arr.shape[0]
    if length == 0:
        return 0,0
    else:
        sum_x = np.sum(arr[:, 0])
        sum_y = np.sum(arr[:, 1])
        return sum_x/float(length), sum_y/float(length)
        

data = [{5036885850: [92.0, 88.73]}, {5036885955: [90.0, 61.73]}, {5036885984: [86.0, 73.03]}, {5036885998: [102.0, 77.54]}]

centroid_list = [list(item.values())[0] for item in order_centroid_list]
centroid_removed_list = []
current_pos = np.array((0, 0))
result_list = []
while len(order_centroid_list) != 0:
    dist_list = [np.linalg.norm(current_pos - np.array(centroid)) for centroid in centroid_list]
    min_dist = min(dist_list)
    item_index = dist_list.index(min_dist)
    next_order = order_centroid_list[item_index]
    result_list.append(next_order)
    centroid_removed_list.append(centroid_list[item_index])
    centroid_list.remove(centroid_list[item_index])
    current_pos = np.array(self.calculate_centroid(centroid_removed_list))
    order_centroid_list.remove(next_order)


print('\nfinal result: ' + str(result_list))
```

I would like to repeat the above steps until the list is empty

Comment: Can you explain the point 2 in easy words.

Comment: What we have to after finding closest order from centroid. Are we calculating centroid from first list or second list? Kindly name the lists in the question.

Comment: @AyushBiswas I have added the extra information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the processed result in batch of length 20, you can just keep another list of batch_results each of length 20, say `final_result_list`. Whenever the `result_list` is of length 20, add the current `result_list` to the `final_result_list`, reinitialize the `current_pos` to `(0,0)`, `centroid_removed_list` and `result_list`.

Now you're good to go! Here's the full code of the problem:

```py
import numpy as np

def calculate_centroid(lst):
    arr = np.array(lst)
    length = arr.shape[0]
    if length == 0:
        return 0,0
    else:
        sum_x = np.sum(arr[:, 0])
        sum_y = np.sum(arr[:, 1])
        return sum_x/float(length), sum_y/float(length)
        

data = [{5036885850: [92.0, 88.73]}, {5036885955: [90.0, 61.73]}, 
 {5036885984: [86.0, 73.03]}, {5036885998: [102.0, 77.54]}, 
 {5036885851: [93.0, 88.0]}, {5036885956: [91.0, 66.73]}, {5036885984: [87.0, 70.0]},
 {5036885998: [101.0, 70.54]},{5036885812: [45.0, 88.73]}, {5036885955: [76.0, 60.73]},
 {5036885911: [83.0, 74.03]}, {5036885910: [108.0, 77.54]},
 {5036885850: [89.0, 76.73]},
 {5036885800: [80.0, 69.45]},
 {50368854801: [86.0, 69.50]},
 {5036885802: [102.0, 77.54]},
 {5036885809: [92.5, 85.0]},
 {5036885803: [91.5, 65.73]},
 {5036885850: [78.0, 76.73]},
 {5036885800: [77.0, 69.45]},
 {50368854801: [85.0, 69.50]},
 {5036885802: [101.50, 89.23]},
 {5036885809: [100.5, 84.84]},
 {5036885803: [100.67, 64.23]},
]

batch_length = 20
centroid_list = [list(item.values())[0] for item in data]
centroid_removed_list = []
current_pos = np.array((0, 0))
result_list = []
final_result_list = []

while len(data) != 0:
    if len(result_list) == batch_length:
        final_result_list.append(result_list)
        result_list = []
        current_pos = np.array((0, 0))
        centroid_removed_list = []
        
    dist_list = [np.linalg.norm(current_pos - np.array(centroid)) for centroid in centroid_list]
    min_dist = min(dist_list)
    item_index = dist_list.index(min_dist)
    next_order = data[item_index]
    result_list.append(next_order)
    centroid_removed_list.append(centroid_list[item_index])
    centroid_list.remove(centroid_list[item_index])
    current_pos = np.array(calculate_centroid(centroid_removed_list))
    data.remove(next_order)

final_result_list.append(result_list)

print('\nfinal result: ' + str(final_result_list))
```

And the result you'll get is:

```
final result: [
    [{5036885955: [76.0, 60.73]}, {5036885800: [77.0, 69.45]}, {5036885800: [80.0, 69.45]}, {50368854801: [85.0, 69.5]}, {50368854801: [86.0, 69.5]}, {5036885984: [87.0, 70.0]}, {5036885911: [83.0, 74.03]}, {5036885984: [86.0, 73.03]}, {5036885850: [78.0, 76.73]}, {5036885850: [89.0, 76.73]}, {5036885956: [91.0, 66.73]}, {5036885803: [91.5, 65.73]}, {5036885955: [90.0, 61.73]}, {5036885998: [101.0, 70.54]}, {5036885803: [100.67, 64.23]}, {5036885809: [92.5, 85.0]}, {5036885998: [102.0, 77.54]}, {5036885802: [102.0, 77.54]}, {5036885851: [93.0, 88.0]}, {5036885850: [92.0, 88.73]}],
    [{5036885812: [45.0, 88.73]}, {5036885809: [100.5, 84.84]}, {5036885802: [101.5, 89.23]}, {5036885910: [108.0, 77.54]}]

]
```

Comment: Confirming the output

Comment: if the `len(data)` is itself less than 20, can this be able to make the batch for that case as well?

Comment: @Sam, yes, it will, the `final_result_list.append(result_list)` outside the function will do the job