# Python IDW with latitude / longitude points

Tags: python, numpy

Utilizing one of the answers from:
[Inverse Distance Weighted (IDW) Interpolation with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104781/inverse-distance-weighted-idw-interpolation-with-python?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I am looking to convert this IDW method into a latitude / longitude problem. For example, if I have latitude/longitude points within a latitude/longitude grid, how much do they influence one another? The idea would be to, in the end, have a 'threshold' in which the distance no longer impacts one another.

Below is a simple attempt to initialize a lat/lon grid with points for the analyses.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def simple_idw(x, y, z, xi, yi):
    dist = distance_matrix(x,y, xi,yi)
    
    # In IDW, weights are 1 / distance
    weights = 1.0 / dist
    
    # Make weights sum to one
    weights /= weights.sum(axis=0)

    # Multiply the weights for each interpolated point by all observed Z-values
    #zi = np.dot(weights.T, z)
    return weights

def distance_matrix(x0, y0, x1, y1):
    obs = np.vstack((x0, y0)).T
    interp = np.vstack((x1, y1)).T

    # Make a distance matrix between pairwise observations
    # Note: from <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871536>
    # (Yay for ufuncs!)
    d0 = np.subtract.outer(obs[:,0], interp[:,0])
    d1 = np.subtract.outer(obs[:,1], interp[:,1])

    return np.hypot(d0, d1)

def plot(x,y,z,grid):
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(grid, extent=(-130,-60, 20,55))
    plt.xlim([-100,-90])
    plt.ylim([30,40])
    plt.scatter(x,y,c=z)
    plt.colorbar()

# Setup: Generate data...
x = np.arange(-100,-90) # Lon points
y = np.arange(30,40) # Lat points
z = np.arange(0,10)/10 # Z values
xii = np.arange(-130,-60,0.01) # Lon grid
yii = np.arange(20,55,0.01) # Lat grid
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xii, yii)
xi, yi = xi.flatten(), yi.flatten()

# Calculate IDW
grid2 = simple_idw(x,y,z,xi,yi)
grid1 = grid2[0,:]
grid0 = grid1.reshape((len(yii), len(xii)))

# Because of the lat/lon stuff, flip our grid upside-down (along x-axis)
grid0 = np.flipud(grid0)

# Comparisons...
plot(x,y,z,grid0)
plt.title('Homemade IDW')
plt.show()
```

[image: img1]

There are several questions, but the most perplexing is: why is the 'heatmap' not behaving properly. For example, the scatterpoints are behaving as one would expect based on the z values, but shouldn't the background 'grid0' also be reflecting this? Furthermore, it looks as if the 'max' values in the background grid are in the bottom-left corner. What am I overlooking here?

Comment: I suspected the normalization at line 13: "weights /= weights.sum(axis=0)" since the values of weights seem to come back negative. But, after debugging for a bit, I'm not sure. Do you think there is an "ideal answer" example that you can provide? Maybe a simple matrix that you checked agaisnt another implementation?