# Finding 3d distances using an inbuilt function in python

Tags: python, list, function, distance

I have 6 lists storing x,y,z coordinates of two sets of positions (3 lists each). I want to calculate the distance between each point in both sets. I have written my own distance function but it is slow. One of my lists has about 1 million entries.
I have tried cdist, but it produces a distance matrix and I do not understand what it means. Is there another inbuilt function that can do this?

Comment: Could you please show some sample input and output

Comment: And your distance function as well as exact problem you're solving... Distance function in Cartesian 3D space is quite simple: `sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2 + (z2 - z1)**2)`, I'm afraid there's not much to optimize.

Comment: `One of my lists has about 1 million entries.` what about the other lists? If they have similar sizes that would be about `10^6 * 10^6 = 10^12` pairs of points and I'm afraid even built-in functions would be slow.

Comment: And I suggest you could try writing a C module and call it in Python, or just use C or C++ entirely to do this calculation.

Comment: Check these
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430091/efficient-distance-calculation-between-n-points-and-a-reference-in-numpy-scipy
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401712/calculate-euclidean-distance-with-numpy

Comment: I haven't actually used it, but People often mention 'numpy' in similar questions.

Answer (score 15):

If possible, use the `numpy` module to handle this kind of things. It is a lot more efficient than using regular python lists.

I am interpreting your problem like this

1. You have two sets of points
2. Both sets have the same number of points (`N`)
3. Point `k` in set 1 is related to point `k` in set 2. If each point is the coordinate of some object, I am interpreting it as set 1 containing the initial point and set 2 the point at some other time t.
4. You want to find the distance `d(k) = dist(p1(k), p2(k))` where `p1(k)` is point number `k` in set 1 and `p2(k)` is point number `k` in set 2.

Assuming that your 6 lists are `x1_coords`, `y1_coords`, `z1_coords` and `x2_coords`, `y2_coords`, `z2_coords` respectively, then you can calculate the distances like this

```
import numpy as np
p1 = np.array([x1_coords, y1_coords, z1_coords])
p2 = np.array([x2_coords, y2_coords, z2_coords])

squared_dist = np.sum((p1-p2)**2, axis=0)
dist = np.sqrt(squared_dist)
```

The distance between `p1(k)` and `p2(k)` is now stored in the numpy array as `dist[k]`.

As for speed: On my laptop with a "Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3517U CPU @ 1.90GHz" the time to calculate the distance between two sets of points with N=1E6 is 45 ms.

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question.  What if you do not have access to numpy?

Comment: If you do not have NumPy, you would do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51665185/3585557.  You certainly would want to use NumPy array if you could because lists are not a great data structure for this type of calculation.

Answer (score 10):

Although this solution uses `numpy`, `np.linalg.norm` could be another solution.

Say you have one point `p0 = np.array([1,2,3])` and a second point `p1 = np.array([4,5,6])`. Then the quickest way to find the distance between the two would be:

```
import numpy as np

dist = np.linalg.norm(p0 - p1)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `math.dist(A, B)` with A and B being an array of coordinates

Answer (score 3):

```
# Use the distance function in Cartesian 3D space:
# Example
import math     
def distance(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2):
d = 0.0
d = math.sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2 + (z2 - z1)**2)
return d
```

Comment: You certainly would want to use a NumPy array if you could because lists are not a great data structure for this type of calculation.