# How to calculate distance between two points in 3D?

Tags: python, arrays, distance

I have two lists. Each list has three lines. The coordinate system is (x,y,z) from up to down for each list. I tried to use array but it didn't work. Here are my codes.

```
import numpy as np
p1 = np.array([list(marker_11_x['11:-.X']), list(marker_11_y['11:-.Y']), 
list(marker_11_z['11:-.Z']) ])
p2 = np.array([list(original_x['13:-.X']), list(original_y['13:-.Y']), 
list(original_z['13:-.Z'])])

squared_dist = np.sum(((p1[0]-p2[0])**2+(p1[1]-p2[1] )**2+(p1[3]-p2[3] )**2), 
axis=0)
dist = np.sqrt(squared_dist)

list A = [-232.34, -233.1, -232.44, -233.02, -232.47, -232.17, -232.6, -232.29, -231.65]
[-48.48, -49.48, -50.81, -51.42, -51.95, -52.25, -52.83, -53.63, -53.24]
[-260.77, -253.6, -250.25, -248.88, -248.06, -247.59, -245.82, -243.98, -243.76]

List B = [-302.07, -302.13, -303.13, -302.69, -303.03, -302.55, -302.6, -302.46, -302.59]
[-1.73, -3.37, -4.92, -4.85, -5.61, -5.2, -5.91, -6.41, -7.4]
[-280.1, -273.02, -269.74, -268.32, -267.45, -267.22, -266.01, -264.79, -264.96]
```

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

TypeError: an integer is required

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
      1 import numpy as np
      2 p1 = np.array([list(marker_11_x['11:-.X']), list(marker_11_y['11:-.Y']), list(marker_11_z['11:-.Z']) ])
----> 3 p2 = np.array([list(original_x['13:-.X']), list(original_y['13:-.Y']), list(original_z['13:-.Z'])])
      4 
      5 squared_dist = np.sum(((p1[0]-p2[0])**2+(p1[1]-p2[1] )**2+(p1[3]-p2[3] )**2), axis=0)

E:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in **getitem**(self, key)
    764         key = com._apply_if_callable(key, self)
    765         try:
--> 766             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    767 
    768             if not is_scalar(result):

E:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   3101         try:
   3102             return self._engine.get_value(s, k,
-> 3103                                           tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
   3104         except KeyError as e1:
   3105             if len(self) > 0 and self.inferred_type in ['integer', 'boolean']:

pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

KeyError: '13:-.X'

Comment: You're going to have to be a LOT more specific than "it didn't work" to get any useful help.  If there was an error, post the complete traceback.  If the results were wrong, post what you got, and what you expected.  See [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I'm pretty new here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171158/how-do-you-get-the-magnitude-of-a-vector-in-numpy

Answer (score 2):

The code and also the formula is gonna be like this :

```py
def distance_finder(one,two) :
    [x1,y1,z1] = one  # first coordinates
    [x2,y2,z2] = two  # second coordinates

    return (((x2-x1)**2)+((y2-y1)**2)+((z2-z1)**2))**(1/2)
```

Comment: Except in unusual circumstances, this should probably be implemented using NumPy arrays, and if possible leveraging prebuilt tools, like [scipy.spatial.distance.cdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html).

Comment: this is wrong and the function doesn't work as stated here. you need to make the points part of the function if you want this function to work for two lists:`def distance_finder(one,two) : 
    [x1,y1,z1] = one # first coordinates
    [x2,y2,z2] = two # second coordinates 
    dist = (((x2-x1)**2)+((y2-y1)**2)+((z2-z1)**2))**(1/2)
    return dist` @StevenC.Howell