# How to calculate the distance between points in three-dimensional space?

Tags: python, calculation

How to calculate the distance between points in three-dimensional space?
I have three one-dimensional arrays, which are used to build a three-dimensional graph. I need to find the distance between the points. I would like to take the interval along the y axis, sort the points and find the length of the line, then the next interval, etc., and then add everything up. But I can't do it. Please tell me how I can do this or some other way of calculating.
using Python

I tried using pdist, dividing the y axis into intervals

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding 3d distances using an inbuilt function in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184992/finding-3d-distances-using-an-inbuilt-function-in-python)

Comment: a good question, but i have voted to close because it has been asked before (as per @Woodford comment).

Answer (score 2):

The following code shows how to use the math.dist() function to calculate the distance between two points in a 3 dimensional space:

```
import math

# Define the points
p1 = (1, 2, 3)
p2 = (4, 5, 6)

# Calculate the distance
distance = math.dist(p1, p2)

# Print the distance
print(distance)
```

In this example, the output is 5.

If you want to do this manually (no libraries) you need to use the Pythagorean theorem.

```
# Define the points
p1 = (1, 2, 3)
p2 = (4, 5, 6)

# Calculate the distance
x1, y1, z1 = p1
x2, y2, z2 = p2

distance = sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2 + (z2 - z1)**2)

# Print the distance
print(distance)
```

Comment: `(x2 - x1)²` is not valid Python

Comment: i modified the answer `(x2 - x1)²`   ->  `(x2 - x1)**2`...