# Multidimensional Euclidean Distance in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, cluster-analysis, euclidean-distance

I want to calculate the Euclidean distance in multiple dimensions (24 dimensions) between 2 arrays. I'm using numpy-Scipy.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy,scipy;

A=numpy.array([116.629, 7192.6, 4535.66, 279714, 176404, 443608, 295522, 1.18399e+07, 7.74233e+06, 2.85839e+08, 2.30168e+08, 5.6919e+08, 168989, 7.48866e+06, 1.45261e+06, 7.49496e+07, 2.13295e+07, 3.74361e+08, 54.5, 3349.39, 262.614, 16175.8, 3693.79, 205865]);

B=numpy.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 151246, 6795630, 4566625, 2.0355328e+08, 1.4250515e+08, 3.2699482e+08, 95635, 4470961, 589043, 29729866, 6124073, 222.3]);
```

However, I used `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(A[numpy.newaxis,:],B,'euclidean')` to calcuate the eucleidan distance.

**But it gave me an error**

```
raise ValueError('XB must be a 2-dimensional array.');
```

I don't seem to understand it.

I looked up `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist` but don't understand how to use it?

**Is there any other better way to do it?**

Comment: Perhaps [`scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean.html#scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean)?

Comment: So, you have 2, 24-dimensional points? In that case, @Mr.E's answer is the best option.  However, when you have more than 2 points, the various `scipy.spatial.distance` functions will be more efficient.

Comment: I thought perhaps I was missing something. Posted as an answer if that solves your problem.

Comment: I would like to say something about the error you received long time ago and it might help others in need. Reading from the docs both arrays A and B need to have the same dimensions. This means that if your first array A has a 2-dimensional shape (like you defined with `A[numpy.newaxis,:]`) also your second array needs to have the same dimensions. Writing `B[numpy.newaxis,:]` should therefore solve the error.

Comment: @JoeKington Who is Mr.E!? :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Perhaps [`scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean.html#scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean)?

> Examples
>
> ```
> >>> from scipy.spatial import distance
> >>> distance.euclidean([1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0])
> 1.4142135623730951
> >>> distance.euclidean([1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0])
> 1.0
> ```

Answer (score 14):

Use either

```
numpy.sqrt(numpy.sum((A - B)**2))
```

or more simply

```
numpy.linalg.norm(A - B)
```

Answer (score 11):

Starting `Python 3.8`, you can use standard library's [`math`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/math.html) module and its new [`dist`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/math.html#math.dist) function, which returns the euclidean distance between two points (given as lists or tuples of coordinates):

```
from math import dist

dist([1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]) # 1.4142135623730951
```

Comment: And it's noticeably faster than scipy's euclidean function! +1

Answer (score 7):

`A` and `B` are 2 points in the 24-D space. You should use `scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean`.

[Doc here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean.html)

```
scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean(A, B)
```

Answer (score 5):

Since all of the above answers refer to numpy and or scipy, just wanted to point out that something really simple can be done with reduce here

```
def n_dimensional_euclidean_distance(a, b):
   """
   Returns the euclidean distance for n>=2 dimensions
   :param a: tuple with integers
   :param b: tuple with integers
   :return: the euclidean distance as an integer
   """
   dimension = len(a) # notice, this will definitely throw a IndexError if len(a) != len(b)

   return sqrt(reduce(lambda i,j: i + ((a[j] - b[j]) ** 2), range(dimension), 0))
```

This will sum all pairs of (a[j] - b[j])^2 for all j in the number of dimensions (note that for simplicity this doesn't support n<2 dimensional distance).

Answer (score 4):

Apart from the already mentioned ways of computing the Euclidean distance, here's one that's close to your original code:

```
scipy.spatial.distance.cdist([A], [B], 'euclidean')
```

or

```
scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(np.atleast_2d(A), np.atleast_2d(B), 'euclidean')
```

This returns a 1×1 `np.ndarray` holding the L2 distance.

Answer (score 1):

Writing your own custom sqaure root sum square is not always safe

You can use math.hypot, numpy.hypot or scipy distance function rather than writing `numpy.sqrt(numpy.sum((A - B)**2))` or `(i**2 + j**2)**0.5`. In your case maybe they can overflow

[refer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69233528/7035448)

### Speed wise

```py
%%timeit
math.hypot(*(A - B))
# 3 µs ± 64.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

```py
%%timeit
numpy.sqrt(numpy.sum((A - B)**2))
# 5.65 µs ± 50.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

## Safety wise

### Underflow

```py
i, j = 1e-200, 1e-200
np.sqrt(i**2+j**2)
# 0.0
```

### Overflow

```py
i, j = 1e+200, 1e+200
np.sqrt(i**2+j**2)
# inf
```

### No Underflow

```py
i, j = 1e-200, 1e-200
np.hypot(i, j)
# 1.414213562373095e-200
```

### No Overflow

```py
i, j = 1e+200, 1e+200
np.hypot(i, j)
# 1.414213562373095e+200
```