# Fastest way to Calculate the Euclidian distance between 2 sets of vectors using numpy or scipy

Tags: numpy, scipy, python-2.x, euclidean-distance

OK I have recently discovered that the the `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist` command is very quick for solving a COMPLETE distance matrix between two vector arrays for source and destination. 
see: [How can the euclidean distance be calculated with numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401712/calculate-euclidean-distance-with-numpy)
I wanted to try to duplicate those performance gains when solving the distance between two equal sized arrays. The distance between two SINGLE vectors is rather straight forward to calculate as shown in the previous link. We can take vectors:

```
    import numpy as np
    A=np.random.normal(size=(3))
    B=np.random.normal(size=(3))
```

and then use ´numpy.linalg.norm´ where

```
    np.linalg.norm(A-B)
```

is equivalent to

```
    temp = A-B
    np.sqrt(temp[0]**2+temp[1]**2+temp[2]**2)
```

which works nicely however when I want to know the distance between two sets of vectors where `my_distance = distance_between( A[i], B[i] ) for all i` the second solution works perfectly. In that as expected:

```
    A=np.random.normal(size=(3,42))
    B=np.random.normal(size=(3,42))     
    temp = A-B
    np.sqrt(temp[0]**2+temp[1]**2+temp[2]**2)
```

gives me a set of 42 distances between the `i`th element of `A` to the `i`th element of `B`. Whereas the `norm` function correctly calculates the norm for the entire matrix giving me a single value that is not what I'm looking for. 
 The behaviour with the 42 distances is what I want to maintain, hopefully with nearly as much speed as I get from `cdist` for solving complete matrices. So the question is whats the most efficient way using python and numpy/scipy to calculate `i` distances between data with shape `(n,i)`?

Thanks,
Sloan

Answer (score 3):

I think you already cracked most of the case yourself. Instead of your last line, however, I would use:

```
np.sqrt(np.sum(temp**2,0))
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll profile that and see how much of a gain that nets me, I was really hoping that there was a way to use one of the C libraries though for further performance.

Comment: Strangely enough its actually 3x faster to use `np.sqrt(temp[0]**2+temp[1]**2+temp[2]**2)` for 1 million elements.

Comment: That's quite an unexpected (and worrying) result indeed ...! The snake works in mysterious ways ... ;-). I'm very interested in why this is, so do you want to post a new question on this, or shall I?

Comment: I'll let you post it but I can share my profile code on the question.

Comment: @SoulNibbler FYI, I posted a new question on the speed issue, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14566564/numpy-sum-may-be-slower-than-python-for-loop

Answer (score 0):

Here are the timed comparisons for the two methods I think are most appropriate:

```
import timeit
In[19]:    timeit.timeit(stmt='np.linalg.norm(x-y,axis=0)', setup='import numpy as np; x,y = np.random.normal(size=(10, 100)), np.random.normal(size=(10, 100))', number=1000000)
Out[19]:   15.132534857024439

In[20]:    timeit.timeit(stmt='np.sqrt(np.sum((x-y),axis=1))', setup='import numpy as np; x,y = np.random.normal(size=(10, 100)), np.random.normal(size=(10, 100))', number=1000000)
Out[20]:   9.417887529009022
```

I'm not surprised the numpy method works faster. I believe as python improves, a lot of these builtin functions will be improved.

Tests were performed on anaconda python version 3.5.2