# numpy.sum may be slower than Python for-loop

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization

When summing an array over a specific axis, the dedicated array method `array.sum(ax)` may actually be slower than a for-loop :

```
v = np.random.rand(3,1e4)

timeit v.sum(0)                             # vectorized method
1000 loops, best of 3: 183 us per loop

timeit for row in v[1:]: v[0] += row        # python loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 39.3 us per loop
```

The vectorized method is more than 4 times slower than an ordinary for-loop! What is going (wr)on(g) here, can't I trust vectorized methods in numpy to be faster than for-loops?

Comment: You are comparing apples and oranges. the second is a 3 items long python loop over a 1000 long C-loop vectorized addition, the first is (probably) 1000 long C, creating loops over 3-4 items. Also the memory layout access is better in the second case, but thats not a big difference.

Comment: In other words... yes you can trust it to be faster... but don't think python is that slow that you cannot do a for loop over 3 items without waiting for ages...

Comment: @seberg I do not agree with the apples and oranges: the for loop here is significantly more efficient than `numpy.sum` and this has to be explained.

Answer (score 9):

No you can't. As your interesting example points out `numpy.sum` can be suboptimal, and a better layout of the operations via explicit for loops can be more efficient.

Let me show another example:

```
>>> N, M = 10**4, 10**4
>>> v = np.random.randn(N,M)
>>> r = np.empty(M)
>>> timeit.timeit('v.sum(axis=0, out=r)', 'from __main__ import v,r', number=1)
1.2837879657745361
>>> r = np.empty(N)
>>> timeit.timeit('v.sum(axis=1, out=r)', 'from __main__ import v,r', number=1)
0.09213519096374512
```

Here you clearily see that `numpy.sum` is optimal if summing on the fast running index (`v` is C-contiguous) and suboptimal when summing on the slow running axis. Interestingly enough an opposite pattern is true for `for` loops:

```
>>> r = np.zeros(M)
>>> timeit.timeit('for row in v[:]: r += row', 'from __main__ import v,r', number=1)
0.11945700645446777
>>> r = np.zeros(N)
>>> timeit.timeit('for row in v.T[:]: r += row', 'from __main__ import v,r', number=1)
1.2647287845611572
```

I had no time to inspect `numpy` code, but I suspect that what makes the difference is contiguous memory access or strided access.

As this examples shows, when implementing a numerical algorithm, a correct memory layout is of great significance. Vectorized code not necessarily solves every problem.

Comment: Yup, memory layout is important, though in his case, he sums over few items... the difference he sees is just that the reduce approach has more overhead inside C due to calling the lowest level loop 10000 times instead of 4 times, and I honestly don't think that is something to worry about itself.

Comment: You can play with different `N, M` in the code above. There are regions of inefficiency in `numpy.sum` and this is normal and not to be worried about, unless this becomes the bottleneck in your application. It was counterintuitive for me that some strategies to regain efficiency that you adopt in C code can be applied at the python interpreter level and outperform numpy! The OP made a really good point. (Final remark: of course if this reduction is the bottleneck, a custom, fine-tuned, C-extension is the best solution; interfaces to vendor libraries (like MKL) should also be analyzed.)