# Python: finding distances between list fields

Tags: python, list, enumerate

Hi I need to calculate distances between every numbers pair in list, including the distance between the last and the first (it's a circle).

Naively i can do something like that:

```
l = [10,-12,350]
ret = []
for i in range(len(l)-1):
    ret.append(abs(l[i] - l[i+1]))
ret.append(l[-1] - l[0])
print ret

out: [22, 362, 340]
```

I tried "enumerate" which is a little bit better way:

```
print [abs(v - (l+[l[0]])[i+1]) for i, v in enumerate(l)]
out: [22, 362, 340]
```

Is there more elegant and "pythonic" way?

Answer (score 5):

I'd argue this is a small improvement. There could well be a cleaner way than this though:

```
print [abs(v - l[(i+1)%len(l)]) for i, v in enumerate(l)]
```

Comment: Much more elegant than I had! Using modulus instead of a trinary if/else is great.

Answer (score 2):

Another method:

```
print map(lambda x,y: abs(x-y), l[1:] + l[:1], l)
```

Comment: You need to calculate the distance (scalar), this gives a vector.

Comment: @HennnyH - yeah just realised :) ta.

Comment: I was editing yours just then (to try fix), arrived at the same expression as you have now :)

Answer (score 1):

Not a huge improvement:

```
>>> [abs(a - b) for a, b in zip(l, l[1:] + l[:-1])]
[22, 362, 340]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy to use numpy...

```
list(numpy.abs(numpy.ediff1d(l, to_end=l[0]-l[-1])))
```

This scales well with longer `l`. Not converting to or from a list will speed things up quite a bit (very often a numpy array can be used in place of a list anyway).

Or you can construct it youself using [`numpy.roll`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html):

```
list(numpy.abs(l - numpy.roll(l, -1)))
```

A few timings:

```
In [37]: l = list(numpy.random.randn(1000))

In [38]: timeit [abs(v - l[(i+1)%len(l)]) for i, v in enumerate(l)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 936 us per loop

In [39]: timeit list(numpy.abs(numpy.ediff1d(l, to_end=l[0]-l[-1])))
1000 loops, best of 3: 367 us per loop

In [40]: _l = numpy.array(l)

In [41]: timeit numpy.abs(numpy.ediff1d(_l, to_end=l[0]-l[-1]))
10000 loops, best of 3: 48.9 us per loop

In [42]: timeit _l = numpy.array(l); list(numpy.abs(_l - numpy.roll(_l, -1)))
1000 loops, best of 3: 350 us per loop

In [43]: timeit numpy.abs(_l - numpy.roll(_l, -1))
10000 loops, best of 3: 32.2 us per loop
```

If raw speed is your thing, quicker still, but not so neat, you can use sliced arrays directly:

```
In [78]: timeit a = numpy.empty(_l.shape, _l.dtype); a[:-1] = _l[:-1] - _l[1:]; a[-1] = _l[-1] - _l[0]; a = numpy.abs(a)
10000 loops, best of 3: 20.5 us per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not as good as other answers in this case, but if used as part of a larger codebase, it could be useful to define an iterator which returns pairs of items over a list, e.g.:

```
def pairs(l):
    if len(l) < 2:
        return

    for i in range(len(l)-1):
        yield l[i], l[i+1]

    yield l[-1], l[0]

print [abs(a - b) for a,b in pairs([10,-12,350])]
```

It's not a one-liner, but is fairly readable.

Answer (score 0):

Combining the answer from icecrime with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401712/calculate-euclidean-distance-with-numpy) provides another pythonic possibility:

```
 print [numpy.linalg.norm(a-b) for a, b in zip(l, l[1:] + l[:-1])]
```