# Reducing function call overhead in python

Tags: python, performance, numpy, cython, overhead-minimization

I developed an application which simulates *N* robots moving in a grid which try to maximize the amount of visited grid cells in a limited amount of steps, meeting in a goal point. It all works correctly, but is horrible slow. It is currently python+numpy+mathplotlib.

Maximum robots there can be have a soft limit of 100 (if it can get higher, it is nice to have).

To do that, I do the following, simplified:

```
while steps > 0:
    for robot in robots:
        agent.calc(robot,steps)
```

A robot is a 1x2 numpy array (x-and-y-coordinates).

The agent here decides what to do. Since I need to switch the tactic and strategy on the fly, I cannot move that logic.

**agent.calc** updates a robot in place, one after another.

cProfiling it returns the [following](http://pastebin.com/Tg2SFsgJ). Extracting the top

```
         39014272 function calls (39010490 primitive calls) in 150.314 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
 12417735   62.807    0.000   62.807    0.000 distance.py:8(taxicab_distance)
   124596   36.882    0.000   36.882    0.000 {numpy.core.multiarray.array}
   113657   30.204    0.000  100.800    0.001 logical_agent.py:16(choose_max_distance_to...)
 12417013    6.579    0.000   69.384    0.000 squaregrid.py:30(distance)
   113700    2.900    0.000  109.769    0.001 logical_agent.py:73(calc)
 11652363    2.625    0.000    2.625    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
   161849    1.653    0.000    1.653    0.000 distance.py:11(euclidean_distance)
   113664    1.632    0.000    1.632    0.000 {sorted}
   114834    1.185    0.000    1.185    0.000 {method 'keys' of 'dict' objects}
   113700    0.695    0.000    1.134    0.000 squaregrid.py:19(neighbours)
```

I implemented different environments for the robots, the most important is **squaregird**. Every environment has its own distance function, since I intended to use different metrics, i.e. Manhattan/taxicab and euclidean. I extracted the distance function into an own **distance.py** file, since I use it in several occasions.

One can see that **taxicab_distance** is called alot, since the agent needs to evaluate the distances of a robots four neighbours and itself to a goal point to see whether the next position can still reach the goal and to maximize the distance to all other robots as a optimizing heuristics.

The function does not do anything fancy, just

```
def taxicab_distance(u, v):
    return np.abs(u[0] - v[0]) + np.abs(u[1] - v[1])
```

I know that python has a pretty high function call overhead, and I assume that that hits the performance. The *{numpy.core.multiarray.array}* can be ignored, I think I know what I am doing wrong there.

Distance call chain: agent -> environment.distance -> taxicab_distance

The question is, **how can I reduce the overhead of calling the function?** I strongly considered using pythons c extensibility, cython, to be more concrete. Will it work? can there be another reason why it is so slow?

Comment: I doing very much that the overhead of *calling* the function is  significant, seeing as it is almost certainly dominated by the actual work done by the function.

Comment: As an experiment, temporarily stop using `taxicab_distance`. Instead, execute function's code directly: `np.abs(u[0] - v[0]) + np.abs(u[1] - v[1])`. Does it help the performance in an appreciable way? My guess is that you should be hunting big (a better algorithm, caching strategies, etc), not small (micro-optimizations like function call overhead).

Comment: Are you taking advantage of vectorized operations? It doesn't look like it. If you don't, using NumPy will actually be slower than using regular lists.

Comment: `method 'keys' of 'dict' objects` - this is unlikely to have a major impact on your runtime, but why are you calling that method? Most of the time, it's unnecessary. If you want to iterate over a dict's keys, just use `for key in d`.

Comment: @user2357112 I dont need to iterate over the dict keys, I store them to animate them later. For every step, I snapshot the grid cells and robot positions for matplotlib animate.

Comment: I inlined the function, and it bought me 20 seconds. But you are totally right, since it takes now 100s with inlined, and 120s without. Another algorithm must be thought of.

Comment: If `u[0]` is a scalar, try `abs(u[0] - v[0]) + abs(u[1] - v[1])`.  This (may) avoid unnecessary conversion to arrays.

Comment: @DanielRoseman CPython's function calling mechanism (the function Py_Call in C) is exceptionally expensive: https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Data_Aggregation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I benchmarked it with inlining, and it took off ~15sec. In the end, I rewrote the number crunching in C++ and used cython for integrating. After that, it took only 1 second.

EDIT: cpython -> cython

Comment: do you really mean 'cpython', or something else?

Comment: I meant cython to call C++ from Python.

Comment: You gave yourself an XY problem; numpy is designed to work with aggregate data because of the exceptionally high overhead python has for making function calls, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401712/how-can-the-euclidean-distance-be-calculated-with-numpy/47542304#47542304. You could have used `np.sum(np.abs(np.subtract(robot, neighbors)), axis=1)`, and perhaps 'neighbors' would be the list of all robots, for cache coherence.

Answer (score 5):

First, I'd rewrite it into:

```
def taxicab_distance(u, v):
     return np.sum(np.abs(u - v))
```

Can you compute `taxicab_distance` for many robots at once?

Comment: exactly. to take advantage of the performance benefits of numpy, you need to vectorize your code; which lifts the inner loops from python to the C-level.

Comment: How would I vectorize my **agent.calc(robot,steps)** ? The underlying data structure is an array of robots(2d-points), and I potentially could return the value of the call instead of updating in place.

Comment: You need to show us what agent.calc does. I suggest creating a question a la "How to vectorize ..."