# Calculate Euclidian Distance in two numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, euclidean-distance

I have two `numpy` arrays as following.

```
X = np.array([-0.34095692,-0.34044722,-0.27155318,-0.21320583,-0.44657865,-0.19587836, -0.29414279, -0.3948753 ,-0.21655774 , -0.34857087])
Y = np.array([0.16305762,0.38554548, 0.10412536, -0.57981103, 0.17927523, -0.22612216, -0.34569697, 0.30463137,0.01301744,-0.42661108])
```

These are x and y coordination of 10 users. I need to find similarity between each user.
For eg :

```
x1 = -0.34095692
y1 = 0.16305762
x2 = -0.34044722
y2 = 0.38554548

Euclidean distance = (|x1-y1|^2 + |x2-y2|^2)^1/2
```

So ultimately I want to get a matrix like following: Help me on achieving this.

[image]

Comment: Sounds good. What is the question?

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart: I have no idea of starting this? Any help?

Comment: Sigh, did you consider asking [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=numpy+euclidean+distance)? It leads you directly to [this successfully-answered question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401712/calculate-euclidean-distance-with-numpy).

Comment: Or, if you prefer, SciPy has a function that handles all distance-related problems: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart: Yes, I found all the resources in the web, problem is not with the calculation of distance, how to make the pairs of array values. I tried this zip(A,A[1:]). But no success.

Comment: How about `zip(X, Y)`?

Comment: do you actually mean `(|x1-x2|^2+|y1-y2|^2)^0.5` instead of `(|x1-y1|^2 - |x2-y2|^2)^1/2` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `zip(X, Y)` to get the coordinate pairs, and if you wanna get the euclidian distance between points, it should be `(|x1-x2|^2+|y1-y2|^2)^0.5`， not `(|x1-y1|^2 - |x2-y2|^2)^1/2`:

```
In [125]: coords=zip(X, Y)

In [126]: from scipy import spatial
     ...: dists=spatial.distance.cdist(coords, coords)

In [127]: dists
Out[127]: 
array([[ 0.        ,  0.22248844,  0.09104884,  0.75377329,  0.10685954,
         0.41534165,  0.5109039 ,  0.15149362,  0.19490308,  0.58971785],
       [ 0.22248844,  0.        ,  0.28973034,  0.9737061 ,  0.23197262,
         0.62852005,  0.73270705,  0.09751671,  0.39258852,  0.81219719],
       [ 0.09104884,  0.28973034,  0.        ,  0.68642072,  0.19047682,
         0.33880688,  0.45038919,  0.23539542,  0.1064197 ,  0.53629553],
       [ 0.75377329,  0.9737061 ,  0.68642072,  0.        ,  0.79415038,
         0.35411306,  0.24770988,  0.90290761,  0.59283795,  0.20443561],
       [ 0.10685954,  0.23197262,  0.19047682,  0.79415038,  0.        ,
         0.47665258,  0.54665574,  0.13560014,  0.28381556,  0.61376196],
       [ 0.41534165,  0.62852005,  0.33880688,  0.35411306,  0.47665258,
         0.        ,  0.15477091,  0.56683251,  0.24003205,  0.25201351],
       [ 0.5109039 ,  0.73270705,  0.45038919,  0.24770988,  0.54665574,
         0.15477091,  0.        ,  0.65808357,  0.36700881,  0.09751671],
       [ 0.15149362,  0.09751671,  0.23539542,  0.90290761,  0.13560014,
         0.56683251,  0.65808357,  0.        ,  0.34181257,  0.73270705],
       [ 0.19490308,  0.39258852,  0.1064197 ,  0.59283795,  0.28381556,
         0.24003205,  0.36700881,  0.34181257,  0.        ,  0.45902146],
       [ 0.58971785,  0.81219719,  0.53629553,  0.20443561,  0.61376196,
         0.25201351,  0.09751671,  0.73270705,  0.45902146,  0.        ]])
```

To get the upper triangle of this array, use `numpy.triu`:

```
In [128]: np.triu(dists)
Out[128]: 
array([[ 0.        ,  0.22248844,  0.09104884,  0.75377329,  0.10685954,
         0.41534165,  0.5109039 ,  0.15149362,  0.19490308,  0.58971785],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.28973034,  0.9737061 ,  0.23197262,
         0.62852005,  0.73270705,  0.09751671,  0.39258852,  0.81219719],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.68642072,  0.19047682,
         0.33880688,  0.45038919,  0.23539542,  0.1064197 ,  0.53629553],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.79415038,
         0.35411306,  0.24770988,  0.90290761,  0.59283795,  0.20443561],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.47665258,  0.54665574,  0.13560014,  0.28381556,  0.61376196],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.15477091,  0.56683251,  0.24003205,  0.25201351],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.65808357,  0.36700881,  0.09751671],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.34181257,  0.73270705],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.45902146],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]])
```

Comment: Thank you very much! At last found it. Thanks a lot again. :)

Comment: @NilaniAlgiriyage glad to help, np ;)

Answer (score 2):

Short snippet that does the job :

```
A = (X-Y)**2
p, q = np.meshgrid(np.arange(10), np.arange(10))
np.sqrt(A[p]-A[q])
```

**Edit** : Explanations

1. `A` is just a precomputed vector with all squared differences.
2. The magic is in `np.meshgrid` : The purpose of this function is to generate all pairs of values in tow different arrays. This is not the best solution because you will get the whole matrix but it's not a big deal for the number of samples you have. Values generated will correspond to the indices of `A`.
3. The indexation part `A[p]` is some kind of magic too. Try it yourself to understand its behaviour.
4. Here the matrix is full of `nan` but that's what you ask for. The true euclidean distance is `+`, not `-`.

p & q :

```
 array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])

array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
   [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
   [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
   [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
   [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
   [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
   [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7],
   [8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8],
   [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]])
```

Comment: This is nice! I havent checked the accuracy of this. Could you please explain this. Any way there are lots of nans right?

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. Yes, that should be + which I have now updated in the question. One last question which I don't get, what all these 'nans' mean?(Are they more close or more separated or what?)

Comment: the difference may be negative, `sqrt` will make negative numbers be `nan`. With the correct formula, you won't get these `nan`s