# Pandas: finding points within maximum distance

Tags: python, pandas, distance

I am trying to find pairs of (x,y) points within a maximum distance of each other. I thought the simplest thing to do would be to generate a DataFrame and go through each point, one by one, calculating if there are points with coordinates (x,y) within distance r of the given point (x_0, y_0). Then, divide the total number of discovered pairs by 2.

```
%pylab inline
import pandas as pd

def find_nbrs(low, high, num, max_d):
    x = random.uniform(low, high, num)
    y = random.uniform(low, high, num)
    points = pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'y':y})

    tot_nbrs = 0

    for i in arange(len(points)):
        x_0 = points.x[i]
        y_0 = points.y[i]

        pt_nbrz = points[((x_0 - points.x)**2 + (y_0 - points.y)**2) < max_d**2]
        tot_nbrs += len(pt_nbrz)
        plot (pt_nbrz.x, pt_nbrz.y, 'r-')

    plot (points.x, points.y, 'b.')
    return tot_nbrs

print find_nbrs(0, 1, 50, 0.1)
```

1. First of all, it's not always finding the right pairs (I see points that are within the stated distance that are not labeled).
2. If I write `plot(..., 'or')`, it highlights all the points. Which means that `pt_nbrz = points[((x_0 - points.x)**2 + (y_0 - points.y)**2) < max_d**2]` returns at least one (x,y). Why? Shouldn't it return an empty array if the comparison is False?
3. How do I do all of the above more elegantly in Pandas? For example, without having to loop through each element.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but you're doing an O(n) search when what I think you want is an O(n^2) search. You're basically checking distance between x0:y0, x1:y1, x2:y2... when what I think you want to do is check x0:y0, x0:y1, ... x1:y0, x1:y1, x1:y2 ....

Comment: But if I'm wrong about what you want then this would work well for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401712/how-can-the-euclidean-distance-be-calculated-with-numpy

Comment: Thanks for the link. I am having some trouble figuring out how to use numpy.linalg.norm to calculate the distance, despite the answer. What format should a and b be in, in the example?

Re: O(n^2), I thought that's what I was doing: i.e., going through each dataframe element and finding all other the elements that satisfy the comparison. That should identify all the twins, twice, so to get the number, I just divide the finall tally by 2.

Comment: Actually, I just realized the answer to question 2: obviously, Pandas compares the distance of the point to itself (which is zero and smaller than max_d), which is why each point is "labeled" as a twin. So, that's another question: how do I perform a comparison that doesn't include comparing the point to itself?

Answer (score 8):

The functionality you're looking for is included in [scipy's spatial distance module](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.html).

Here's an example of how you could use it. The real magic is in `squareform(pdist(points))`.

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

points = np.random.uniform(-.5, .5, (1000,2))

# Compute the distance between each different pair of points in X with pdist.
# Then, just for ease of working, convert to a typical symmetric distance matrix
# with squareform.
dists = squareform(pdist(points))

poi = points[4] # point of interest
dist_min = .1
close_points = dists[4] < dist_min

print("There are {} other points within a distance of {} from the point "
    "({:.3f}, {:.3f})".format(close_points.sum() - 1, dist_min, *poi))
```

`There are 27 other points within a distance of 0.1 from the point (0.194, 0.160)`

For visualization purposes:

```
f,ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=
    dict(aspect='equal', xlim=(-.5, .5), ylim=(-.5, .5)))
ax.plot(points[:,0], points[:,1], 'b+ ')
ax.plot(poi[0], poi[1], ms=15, marker='s', mfc='none', mec='g')
ax.plot(points[close_points,0], points[close_points,1],
    marker='o', mfc='none', mec='r', ls='')  # draw all points within distance

t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 512)
circle = dist_min*np.vstack([np.cos(t), np.sin(t)]).T
ax.plot((circle+poi)[:,0], (circle+poi)[:,1], 'k:') # Add a visual check for that distance
plt.show()
```

[image]