# Biopython PDB: calculate distance between an atom and a point

Tags: python, distance, point, biopython, protein-database

Using a typical pdb file, I am able to calculate the distance between two atoms in a structure using a method similar to that presented in the Biopython documentation.  Shown here:

```
from Bio import PDB
parser = PDB.PDBParser()

pdb1 ='./4twu.pdb' 
structure = parser.get_structure("4twu", pdb1) 
model = structure[0] 
chain = model['A'] 
residue1 = chain[1] 
residue2 = chain[2]
atom1 = residue1['CA'] 
atom2 = residue2['CA'] 

distance = atom1-atom2 

print(distance)
```

Is there a method within Biopython to calculate the distance from an atom to a fixed point with xyz coordinates?  If not Biopython, what would be the best method to solve this problem?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your atom1 object stores the coordinates in the `coord` attribute (it's a NumPy array), e.g.

```
>>> print(atom1.coord)
[ 26.26600075  25.41300011   2.84200001]
```

If you want to calculate the distance to another point in space you need to define it in a similar format.

```
import numpy
x = 1
y = 1
y = 1
v = numpy.array((x, y, z), dtype=float)
```

and you can then calculate the [distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401712/how-can-the-euclidean-distance-be-calculated-with-numpy) with NumPy.

```
distance = numpy.linalg.norm(atom1.coord - v)
```

Comment: Works perfectly.  Thanks Ashafix.

Comment: Yes. This is basically what the Atom objects are doing for you via the subtraction in your question, ``__sub__`` is defined in the atom class as taking the norm of the difference in the coordinate vectors.