# How to calculate distances between receptor particular atom of chain A (CZ) atoms against a list of atoms on chain B

Tags: python, biopython

thank you so much for your time, in advance.
I want to calculate the distances of one atom from chain A against multiple atoms from chain B. for Exp:

My PDB file has these entries

Chain A
ATOM     32  CZ  ARG A  89      -9.472  17.209  -4.849  1.00 49.73           C

Chain B
ATOM    538  O4'  DG B   2      -6.257  16.810  11.821  1.00 71.16           O
ATOM    539  C3'  DG B   2      -4.271  15.614  11.464  1.00 73.87           C

Chain C
ATOM    830  O3'  DC C   2      -8.757   5.249 -25.109  1.00 30.80           O
ATOM    831  C2'  DC C   2      -6.307   4.905 -25.202  1.00 32.20           C

better:

```
ATOM     32  CZ  ARG A   89     -9.472  17.209  -4.849  1.00 49.73           C

ATOM    538  O4' DG  B   2      -6.257  16.810  11.821  1.00 71.16           O 
ATOM    539  C3' DG  B   2      -4.271  15.614  11.464  1.00 73.87           C

ATOM    830  O3* DC  C   2      -8.757   5.249 -25.109  1.00 30.80           O
ATOM    831  C2* DC  C   2      -6.307   4.905 -25.202  1.00 32.20           C
```

Now I want to calculate the distances between chain A CZ atom against chain B&C following atoms O4', C3', O3', C2' etc.

Please guide me. Thanks

Comment: start from here Biopython PDB: calculate distance between an atom and a point https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37079684/biopython-pdb-calculate-distance-between-an-atom-and-a-point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here my attempt:

```
from Bio import PDB
parser = PDB.PDBParser()

pdb1 ='pdb_test.pdb' 
structure = parser.get_structure("pdb_test", pdb1) 

atom1 = structure[0]["A"][89]["CZ"]

for model in structure:
    for chain in model:
        for residue in chain:
            for atom in residue:
                if chain.id !='A':
                    print(atom1 , '  -  ',atom ,  '  =  ',atom1 - atom)
```

output:

```
<Atom CZ>   -   <Atom O4'>   =   16.981882
<Atom CZ>   -   <Atom C3'>   =   17.196173
<Atom CZ>   -   <Atom O3'>   =   23.537636
<Atom CZ>   -   <Atom C2'>   =   23.992712
```