# python multiprocessing for euclidean distance loop

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

i have euclidean distance code but its running very slow since the data is big. can i get faster with python multiprocessing ?

this is my code

```
def euclidean_distance(self,x1, x2):
    distance = 0.0
    for i in range(len(x1)):
        distance += pow( x1[i] - x2[i], 2)
    return math.sqrt(distance)
```

how to use multipocessing pool ?
can i go with pool.map for this function ?

```
#multiprocessing
pool = multiprocessing.pool(processes=2)
        dist = pool.map(self.euclidean_distance(test.vector,point.vector),range(len(x1))
```

it doesnt work since range(len(x1) is outside def. any help appreciated for quicken that function, thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401712/how-can-the-euclidean-distance-be-calculated-with-numpy

Comment: What are `test` and `point` in your example code? I'm a bit doubtful that using `multiprocessing` can help you with this code since the amount of work you do for each function call is very small. I'd expect the overhead of serializing and copying the data between processes would be much more than the cost of doing the actual calculation in the main process.

Comment: How long are these vectors? As Burhan suggest, you should try to speed things up with Numpy before you try multiprocessing, since the overheads of using multiprocessing probably outweigh its benefits.

Comment: its an array, i am calculating distance between array, okay thanks

Comment: @PM2Ring can u give me example doing it with numpy ? thanks

Comment: Yes, we understand that you're trying to get the euclidean distance between pairs of 1D arrays. But you haven't told us how many elements are in each of these arrays. To see how to do this using Numpy please take a look at the link that Burhan Khalid posted in the top comment.

Comment: If Burhan Khalid's link answers your question we can close this one as a duplicate.

Comment: sorry i didnt notice there is a link, thanks, i ll try it