# Pyspark euclidean distance between entry and column

Tags: pyspark, euclidean-distance

I am working with pyspark, and wondering if there is any smart way to get euclidean dstance between one row entry of array and the whole column. For instance, there is a dataset like this.

```
+--------------------+---+
|            features| id|
+--------------------+---+
|[0,1,2,3,4,5     ...|  0|
|[0,1,2,3,4,5     ...|  1|
|[1,2,3,6,7,8     ...|  2|
```

Choose one of the column i.e. id==1, and calculate the euclidean distance. In this case, the result should be [0,0,sqrt(1+1+1+9+9+9)].
Can anybody figure out how to do this efficiently?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you need distances between only a single entry and an entire column or will you also need between entire two columns? For first case, it is pretty simple by creating a UDF with that single entry and feeding the column to it. In second case, it becomes a little complicated.

Comment: @mayankagrawal It is the first case I am looking for. I am not so familiar with UDF, so can you give me some hint on that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want euclidean for a fixed entry with a column, simply do this.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType
from scipy.spatial import distance

fixed_entry = [0,3,2,7...] #for example, the entry against which you want distances
distance_udf = F.udf(lambda x: float(distance.euclidean(x, fixed_entry)), FloatType())
df = df.withColumn('distances', distance_udf(F.col('features')))
```

Your df will have a column of distances.

Comment: File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 71, in <lambda>
    return lambda *a: f(*a)
  File "<ipython-input-32-5533c08845eb>", line 6, in <lambda>
  File "/home/yhkwon/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/spatial/distance.py", line 433, in euclidean
    dist = norm(u - v)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (31,) (2,) 
I am trying your method, and this is what I am getting if i try to collect the output. I selected one row from the dataframe for fixed_entry.

Comment: Sorry, I used the Row object instead of the array inside it. Thanks!

Comment: is there any way not using scipy library?

Comment: @staticmethod
I created my own function like this not to use scipy library    
def euclidean(x, y):
        distance = 0
        for i in range(len(x)):
            distance += ((x[i] - y[i]) * (x[i] - y[i]))
        return float(math.sqrt(distance))

Comment: yes you can avoid the use of scipy. If numpy is fine with you, use dist = numpy.linalg.norm(a-b). If you dont want to use any library your method is fine but I doubt it will be faster than libraries. Anyways, you can write the for loop in a single line like this math.sqrt(sum( (a - b)**2 for a, b in zip(a, b))). Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/4169284/7045987

Answer (score 4):

You can do `BucketedRandomProjectionLSH` [1] to get a cartesian of distances between your data frame.

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import BucketedRandomProjectionLSH

brp = BucketedRandomProjectionLSH(
    inputCol="features", outputCol="hashes", seed=12345, bucketLength=1.0
)
model = brp.fit(df)
model.approxSimilarityJoin(df, df, 3.0, distCol="EuclideanDistance")
```

You can also get distances for one row to column with `approxNearestNeighbors` [2], but the results are limited by `numNearestNeighbors`, so you could give it the count of the entire data frame.

```
one_row = df.where(df.id == 1).first().features
model.approxNearestNeighbors(df2, one_row, df.count()).collect()
```

Also, make sure to convert your data to Vectors!

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

to_dense_vector = F.udf(Vectors.dense, VectorUDF())
df = df.withColumn('features', to_dense_vector('features'))
```

[1] https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html?highlight=approx#pyspark.ml.feature.BucketedRandomProjectionLSH

[2] https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html?highlight=approx#pyspark.ml.feature.BucketedRandomProjectionLSHModel.approxNearestNeighbors

Comment: For approxSimilarityJoin, 3.0 is the threshold parameter above which all distances will be rejected. So it will not give a complete array with all distances.

Comment: I am actually using this library, but there is problem when the dataset is too small. I am working on oversampling, and when the minority class is too small(ex 5), if I do the BucketedRandomProjection LSH, i think only one  element is placed in the bucket and no any other neighbor. That's why i am looking for brute force. Any solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an implementation using SQL Function power() to compute Euclidean distance between matching rows in two dataframes

```
cols2Join = ['Key1','Key2']
colsFeature =['Feature1','Feature2','Feature3','Feature4']
columns = cols2Join + colsFeature

valuesA = [('key1value1','key2value1',111,22,33,.334),('key1value3','key2value3', 333,444,12,.445),('key1value5','key2value5',555,666,101,.99),('key1value7','key2value7',777,888,10,.019)]
table1 = spark.createDataFrame(valuesA,columns)
valuesB = [('key1value1','key2value1',22,33,3,.1),('key1value3','key2value3', 88,99,4,1.23),('key1value5','key2value5',4,44,1,.998),('key1value7','key2value7',9,99,1,.3)]
table2= spark.createDataFrame(valuesB,columns)

#Create the sql expression using list comprehension, we use sql function power to compute euclidean distance inline
beginExpr='power(('
InnerExpr = ['power((a.{}-b.{}),2)'.format(x,x) for x in colsFeature]
InnerExpr = '+'.join(str(e) for e in InnerExpr)
endExpr ='),0.5) AS EuclideanDistance'
distanceExpr = beginExpr + InnerExpr + endExpr
Expr =  cols2Join+  [distanceExpr]

#now just join the tables and use Select Expr to get Euclidean distance
outDF = table1.alias('a').join(table2.alias('b'),cols2Join,how="inner").selectExpr(Expr)

display(outDF)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find euclidean distances between only one particular row and every other row in dataframe, then you can filter & collect that row and  pass it to `udf`.

But, if you need to calculate  distance between all pairs You need to use join.
Repartition the dataframe by id, it will speed up the join operation. No need to calculate full pairwise matrix, just calculate the upper or lower half and replicate it. I wrote a function for myself based on the this logic.

```
 df = df.repartition("id")
 df.cache()
 df.show()


 #metric = any callable function to calculate distance b/w two vectors
 def pairwise_metric(Y, metric, col_name="metric"):

     Y2 = Y.select(f.col("id").alias("id2"), 
                 f.col("features").alias("features2"))

     # join to create lower or upper half
     Y = Y.join(Y2, Y.id < Y2.id2, "inner")

     def sort_list(x):

         x = sorted(x, key=lambda y:y[0])
         x = list(map(lambda y:y[1], x))

         return(x)

     udf_diff = f.udf(lambda x,y: metric(x,y), t.FloatType())
     udf_sort = f.udf(sort_list, t.ArrayType(t.FloatType()))

     Yid = Y2.select("id2").distinct().select("id2", 
          f.col("id2").alias("id")).withColumn("dist", f.lit(0.0))

     Y = Y.withColumn("dist", udf_diff("features", 
              "features2")).drop("features","features2")

     # just swap the column names and take union to get the other half
     Y =Y.union(Y.select(f.col("id2").alias("id"),
          f.col("id").alias("id2"), "dist"))
     # union for the diagonal elements of distance matrix
     Y = Y.union(Yid)

     st1 = f.struct(["id2", "dist"]).alias("vals")
     # groupby , aggregate and sort
     Y = (Y.select("id",st1).groupBy("id").agg(f.collect_list("vals").
                             alias("vals")).withColumn("dist",udf_sort("vals")).drop("vals"))

     return(Y.select(f.col("id").alias("id1"), f.col("dist").alias(col_name)))
```

Comment: Wont this be something similar to cartesian added with the fact there will be no replicas?

Comment: Since you will crossjoin dataframe with itself,more than half of pairwise distance calculations would be unnecessary.