# Compute similarity in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, similarity, sentence-similarity

I have a `csv` file contains some data, I want select the similar data with an input.
my data is like:

```
H1      | H2      | H3
--------+---------+----------
A       | 1       | 7
B       | 5       | 3
C       | 7       | 2
```

And the data point that I want find data similar to that in my `csv` is like : `[6, 8]`.

Actually I want find rows that `H2` and `H3` of data set is similar to input, and It return `H1`.

I want use pyspark and some similarity measure like Euclidean Distance, Manhattan Distance, Cosine Similarity or machine learning algorithm.

Comment: could you please explain a bit more? what outcome are you looking for with `[6, 8]`?

Comment: I want calculate cosin similarity between csv rows and my inputs. In above example 3 number that show the similarly.

Comment: have a look at [this Q](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46725290/8279585)

Comment: @samkart tanks a lot. I think that links help to me. but i have some problem with [BucketedRandomProjectionLSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72897923/what-do-fit-in-bucketedrandomprojectionlsh-in-spark)