# Computing euclidean distance with multiple list in python

Tags: python, list, euclidean-distance

I'm writing a simple program to compute the euclidean distances between multiple lists using python. This is the code I have so fat

```
import math
euclidean = 0
euclidean_list = []
euclidean_list_complete = []

test1 = [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 152.0, 12.29], [0.0, 0.0, 0.357, 245.0, 10.4], [0.0, 0.0, 0.10, 200.0, 11.0]]

test2 = [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 72.0, 12.9], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 80.0, 11.3]]

for i in range(len(test2)):
    for j in range(len(test1)):
        for k in range(len(test1[0])):
            euclidean += pow((test2[i][k]-test1[j][k]),2)

        euclidean_list.append(math.sqrt(euclidean))
        euclidean = 0

    euclidean_list_complete.append(euclidean_list)


print euclidean_list_complete
```

my problem with this code is it doesn't print the output i want properly. The output should be 
`[[80.0023, 173.018, 128.014], [72.006, 165.002, 120.000]]`

but instead, it prints

`[[80.00232559119766, 173.01843095173416, 128.01413984400315, 72.00680592832875, 165.0028407300917, 120.00041666594329], [80.00232559119766, 173.01843095173416, 128.01413984400315, 72.00680592832875, 165.0028407300917, 120.00041666594329]]`

I'm guessing it has something to do with the loop. What should I do to fix it? By the way, I don't want to use numpy or scipy for studying purposes

If it's unclear, I want to calculate the distance between lists on test2 to each lists on test1

Comment: It's because `dist(a, b) = dist(b, a)`. The easiest way to remove the redundant computations is to loop over only half the items.

Comment: What @MateenUlhaq says is correct. You can find these things by stepping through the code with a debugger, if you have one. Or by tracing all the steps by hand. It's labor-intensive but can really help you learn. Anyway, good luck with your studies!

Comment: i'm trying to understand question, lets `test1 has [a,b,c]` and `test2 has [c,d]`, which points you are taking to calculate distance?

Comment: @S.L.Barth I tried to visualize it using a visualizer tool from a certain website, and I got it right until the 1st iteration of i. But then I realized the remaining values would also got in the euclidean_list list on the 2nd iteration. In that case, shouldn't it print [[80.00232559119766, 173.01843095173416, 128.01413984400315], [80.00232559119766, 173.01843095173416, 128.01413984400315, 72.00680592832875, 165.0028407300917, 120.00041666594329]] ?

Comment: @MohanBabu my bad, I should've written the question more precisely. Let test1 be [a, b, c] and test2 be [d, e]. I want to calculate the distance between d to a,b,c and e to a,b,c

Comment: @MateenUlhaq what exactly do you mean by looping over only half the items? I'm sorry I didn't understand it completely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question has partly been answered by @Evgeny. The answer the OP posted to his own question is an example how to not write Python code. Here is a shorter, faster and more readable solution, given `test1` and `test2` are lists like in the question:

```
def euclidean(v1, v2):
    return sum((p-q)**2 for p, q in zip(v1, v2)) ** .5

d2 = []
for i in test2:
    foo = [euclidean(i, j) for j in test1]
    d2.append(foo)


print(d2)
#[[80.00232559119766, 173.01843095173416, 128.01413984400315],
# [72.00680592832875, 165.0028407300917, 120.00041666594329]]
```

Comment: I do realize that my own code is not good which is why I said I'm doing it for studying purposes. But this answer is very good and very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @MaxPowers - from your code I finally understand the intent of distances between two groups vectors, asked by OP

Comment: Once we are on a path for improvements, there can also list comp instead of loop for computing pair-wise listances ```def group_distance(vector_list1, vector_list2):
     return [[euclidean(v1, v2) for v2 in vector_list2] for v1 in vector_list1]```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve for 3 vectors, but for two the code has to be much, much simplier:

```
test2 = [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 72.0, 12.9], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 80.0, 11.3]]

def distance(list1, list2):
    """Distance between two vectors."""
    squares = [(p-q) ** 2 for p, q in zip(list1, list2)]
    return sum(squares) ** .5

d2 = distance(test2[0], test2[1])
```

With `numpy` is even a [shorter statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401712/how-can-the-euclidean-distance-be-calculated-with-numpy).

PS. python 3 recommened

Comment: Cheers, this is very helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
test1 = [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 152.0, 12.29], [0.0, 0.0, 0.357, 245.0, 10.4], [0.0, 0.0, 0.10, 200.0, 11.0]]

test2 = [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 72.0, 12.9], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 80.0, 11.3]]

final_list = []

for a in test2:
    temp = [] #temporary list
    for b in test1:
        dis = sum([pow(a[i] - b[i], 2) for i in range(len(a))])
        temp.append(round(pow(dis, 0.5),4))

    final_list.append(temp)
print(final_list)
```

Answer (score -2):

I got it, the trick is to create the first euclidean list inside the first for loop, and then deleting the list after appending it to the complete euclidean list

```
import math
euclidean = 0

euclidean_list_complete = []

test1 = [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 152.0, 12.29], [0.0, 0.0, 0.357, 245.0, 10.4], [0.0, 0.0, 0.10, 200.0, 11.0]]

test2 = [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 72.0, 12.9], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 80.0, 11.3]]

for i in range(len(test2)):
    euclidean_list = []
    for j in range(len(test1)):
        for k in range(len(test1[0])):
            euclidean += pow((test2[i][k]-test1[j][k]),2)      
        euclidean_list.append(math.sqrt(euclidean))
        euclidean = 0
        euclidean_list.sort(reverse=True)
    euclidean_list_complete.append(euclidean_list)
    del euclidean_list

print euclidean_list_complete
```