# Euclidian distance for two multidimentionnal array

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to find the **euclidian distanc**e between two **numpy.ndarray**.

```
lower_boundary = 0
upper_boundary = 1
n = 4 # dimension
sample_size = 3

np.random.seed(9001) # set the seed to yield reproducible results

X2 = np.random.uniform( low=lower_boundary, high=upper_boundary, size=(sample_size, n) )
Y2 = np.random.uniform( low=lower_boundary, high=upper_boundary, size=(sample_size, n) )

print( 'X2: ', X2 )
print( 'Y2: ', Y2 )
```

1. How can i implement this calculation from scratch, by using **np.sum** and **np.sqrt** instead of importing **euclidean_distances** from **sklearn.metrics.pairwise**

Thanks for all

Comment: Do you know how to do this by hand? Say you have two 3x3 matrices. What is the formula for the distance between them?

Comment: How do you define the distance between matrices of dimension greater than one?

Comment: What have you tried? This is a fairly common problem, have you found any other stackoverflow questions that address it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can the Euclidean distance be calculated with NumPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401712/how-can-the-euclidean-distance-be-calculated-with-numpy)

Answer (score 0):

Eucledian Distance be D(i,j). Then D(i,j) corresponds to the pairwise distance between row i in X and row j in Y. In this case, the size of distance matrix will be 3 by 3.

```
final_sum=np.zeros([sample_size,sample_size])
for row_inX in range(0, sample_size):
for row_inY in range(0, sample_size):
    final_sum[row_inX][row_inY]= np.sqrt(np.sum((X2[row_inX]- Y2[row_inY])**2))
print(final_sum)
```