# Calculate the distance between all point in an array and another point in two dimensions

Tags: python, python-3.x, distance

I have a two dimensional point, lets call it

```
p1 = (x,y)
```

and an array of points,

```
p2 = [(x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3)...]
```

I want to build an array that calculates the distance between each entry in p2 and the point p1. Next, I need to find the smallest distance between a point in p2 and p1 and return the original coordinates in p2. So far, I have tried the following:

```
dist1 = np.sqrt(p1.x**2 + p1.y**2)
dist2 = np.sqrt(p2.x**2 + p2.y**2)
dist = dist2-dist1
```

Which returns the error "operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (1265,)"

As far as finding the minimum distance, I think I need to use the numpy min function as follows

```
import numpy as np
np.min(dist)
```

But I am stuck on how to return the x nd y coordinates once I calculate the distance.

Comment: Your distance calc looks wrong to me.

Comment: @StephenRauch do you have a suggestion? What part of the distance calculation looks incorrect?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance

Comment: @StephenRauch correcting to the correct distance formula returns the same error.  I think I need a better method to match each object in  p2 with p1. The error indicates that I cannot use this method to match two arrays of different length.

Comment: This distance formula in the question is still broken...

Comment: I used: dist1 = ((pos2.ra-pos1.ra)**2)
        dist2 = ((pos2.dec-pos1.dec)**2)
        dist = np.sqrt(dist1+dist2)  The error is still the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can the Euclidean distance be calculated with NumPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401712/how-can-the-euclidean-distance-be-calculated-with-numpy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you use scipy's `cdist` to achieve this, but you need to specify the arrays in a different format.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

x = np.array([[2,1]])
y = np.array([[1,0], [2,3], [4,3]])

d = cdist(x,y)
```

And `d` is the array with all the distances.

In general, when specifying sets of points, the format `p2 = [(x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3)...]` is not very convenient for manipulation with libraries such as numpy / scipy / pandas. Typically you might prefer `np.array([[x1,y1], [x2,y2], [x3,x3]])` instead.

To get the minimum distance, use

```
idx = np.argmin(d)
```

`idx` returns the value of the *index* of the array with the minimum distance (in this case, `0`).

So if you do `y[idx]` it will return the point with minimum distance (in this case `[1, 0]`).

Comment: Using this, I get an error: "XA must be a 2-dimensional array." @JARS

Comment: Did you put the two square brackets in `x = np.array([[2,1]])`?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna calculate the distance and find the smallest without using any package, then you can try something like this

```
import sys

minimum_distance = sys.maxsize
minimum_point = (0,0)

for point in p2:
    distance = math.sqrt((p[0] - point[0]) ** 2 + (p[1] - point[1]) ** 2)
    if distance < minimum_distance:
        minimum_distance = distance
        minimum_point = point

print("Point with minimum distance", minimum_point)
```