# How to apply euclidean distance to dataframe. Calculate each row

Tags: python, dataframe, euclidean-distance

Please help me, I have the problem. It's been about 2 weeks but I don't get it yet.

So, I want to use "apply" in dataframe, which I got from Alphavantage API. 
I want to apply euclidean distance to each row of dataframe.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial import distance
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
from services.KEY import getApiKey


ts = TimeSeries(key=getApiKey(), output_format='pandas')
```

And in my picture I got this

[My chart (sorry can't post image because of my reputation)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPUPa.png)

In my code

```
stock, meta_data = ts.get_daily_adjusted(symbol, outputsize='full')
stock = stock.sort_values('date')

open = stock['1. open'].values
low = stock['3. low'].values
high = stock['2. high'].values
close = stock['4. close'].values
sorted_date = stock.index.get_level_values(level='date')

stock_numpy_format = np.stack((sorted_date, open, low
                               ,high, close), axis=1)
df = pd.DataFrame(stock_numpy_format, columns=['date', 'open', 'low', 'high', 'close'])

df = df[df['open']>0]
df = df[(df['date'] >= "2016-01-01") & (df['date'] <= "2018-12-31")]
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

df['close_next'] = df['close'].shift(-1)
df['daily_return'] = df['close'].pct_change(1)
df['daily_return'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
stock_numeric_close_dailyreturn = df['close', 'daily_return']
stock_normalized = (stock_numeric_close_dailyreturn - stock_numeric_close_dailyreturn.mean()) / stock_numeric_close_dailyreturn.std()

euclidean_distances = stock_normalized.apply(lambda row: distance.euclidean(row, date_normalized) , axis=1)
distance_frame = pd.DataFrame(data={"dist": euclidean_distances, "idx":euclidean_distances.index})
distance_frame.sort_values("dist", inplace=True)
second_smallest = distance_frame.iloc[1]["idx"]
most_similar_to_date = df.loc[int(second_smallest)]["date"]
```

And I want that my chart like this

[The chart that I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XieFg.png)

And the code from this picture

```
distance_columns = ['Close', 'DailyReturn']
stock_numeric = stock[distance_columns]
stock_normalized = (stock_numeric - stock_numeric.mean()) / stock_numeric.std()
stock_normalized.fillna(0, inplace = True)
date_normalized = stock_normalized[stock["Date"] == "2016-06-29"]
euclidean_distances = stock_normalized.apply(lambda row: distance.euclidean(row, date_normalized), axis = 1)
distance_frame = pandas.DataFrame(data = {"dist": euclidean_distances, "idx": euclidean_distances.index})
distance_frame.sort_values("dist", inplace=True)
second_smallest = distance_frame.iloc[1]["idx"]
most_similar_to_date = stock.loc[int(second_smallest)]["Date"]
```

I tried to figure it out, the "apply" in the df.apply from pandas format and from pandas.csv_reader is different.
Is there any alternative to have same output in different format (pandas and csv)

Thank you!

nb: sorry if my english bad.

Comment: 1) what are stock_normalized, df and stock? 2) What is the actual question, are you getting ts with a output_format='csv'? 3) most likely imports pd == pandas, and the csv_reader from pandas is generating a dataframe, so it should have the exact same apply !? Are you sure your predicted saturated value (limited to at most +/- 2450) is coming from this part of the code?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll fix it.

Comment: any reason why you need to use `.apply()` at all? `distance.euclidean` should also work on vector. Better yet, use `numpy.linalg.norm(a-b)` as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401712/how-can-the-euclidean-distance-be-calculated-with-numpy/21986532)

Comment: Also, I think it's best to clarify that you have many questions lumped into one. On one hand, you have problem with the `.apply()`, on another hand you have issue with your chart not looking like the example.

Comment: ok I get it. Finnaly it's because of the stock I use. I've tried some of different stock code and some of them give good result.

thank you for Mr. @B.Go

Comment: thank you Mr. @AdityaSantoso