# How to change the code to find the euclidean distance (not cosine) between words in a word2vec impementation?

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec, similarity, euclidean-distance

The following code when run gives the cosine distance between two words.

model.wv.distance('word1','word2')

How do I find the euclidean distance between two words?
I am using gensim for word2vec implementation

Answer (score 1):

Usually the cosine-distance is preferred in this domain.

But if you needed euclidean distance, you can just request the raw vectors for each word, find the difference, and use a basic `numpy.linalg.norm' operation, as per this StackOverflow answer:

[How can the Euclidean distance be calculated with NumPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401712/how-can-the-euclidean-distance-be-calculated-with-numpy)

Specifically:

```
import numpy as np
euc_dist = np.linalg.norm(model.wv['word1'] - model.wv['word2']))
```

Comment: Thanks friend. I was comparing between cosine and Euclidean distances