# I want to model Euclidean distance using MIT-BIH ECG

Tags: python, csv

I am not good at Python. 
I have a csv file, and I want to calculate cosine simularity or Euclidian Distance using them.
But, I don't know how to use the csv file, so please let me know the documents or materials I can use.

Comment: There are a plenty of tutorials on the web for what you are looking for about csv like [this](https://realpython.com/python-csv/). For cosine similarity, you can check [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find euclidean distance using `scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean` or `numpy.linalg.norm`. Your problem statement can be broken down as follows:

## Steps

1. Load data from a CSV
2. Calculate euclidean distance

## Solution

You would need these libraries.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean
```

### Step-1

Load CSV. We assume here that your CSV file has 2 or more columns and the target columns names are `x` and `y`.

```py
df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv")
x = df['x']
y = df['y']
```

### Step-2

I will show given you have two arrays of data `x` and `y` how you could calculate euclidean distance.

#### Make Data (if necessary)

```py
# If you do not have data, make it
x = np.arange(10)
y = np.arange(10,20)
```

#### Calculate Euclidean Distance

```py
# using scipy
scipy_d = euclidean(x,y)

# using numpy
numpy_d = np.linalg.norm(x-y)
```

## References

I would encourage you to see the following.

1. [How can the Euclidean distance be calculated with NumPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401712/how-can-the-euclidean-distance-be-calculated-with-numpy)
2. [`scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean.html)
3. [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: @park I am glad the solution helped you out. Thank you for choosing it as the `accepted` answer. Could you please also **`vote-up`** this answer?