# calculate distacne of two cartesian coordinates

Tags: python, numpy

I have cartesian coordinates of two points in a txt file.

```
-0.329637489    3.481200000     1.740200000
2.389059814     1.000230000     8.653210000
```

I have read the file

```
with open('coord.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    
lines_1 = [x.strip() for x in lines]
lines_2 = [x.split() for x in lines_1]
lines_2 = np.array(lines_2).astpye(float)
```

```
>> array([[-0.32963749,  3.4812    ,  1.7402    ],
       [ 2.38905981,  1.00023   ,  8.65321   ]])
```

I can select each entity of the matrix to calculate the distance between the points. But I want to learn what API/library would give the most effective result and how/why.

If there is a computational cost difference, the difference would come from the language they used for the API/library?

Comment: This question is too broad as it includes reading a file, process and convert strings and doing calculations. Show your code and ask for a specific issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can the Euclidean distance be calculated with NumPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401712/how-can-the-euclidean-distance-be-calculated-with-numpy)

Answer (score 1):

You can load the data directly in a numpy `array` using `np.loadtxt`:

```
a= np.loadtxt('../filename.txt')
a
array([[-0.32963749,  3.4812    ,  1.7402    ],
       [ 2.38905981,  1.00023   ,  8.65321   ]])
```

Then perform operations to compute distance:

```
d = np.sqrt(np.sum((a[0]-a[1])**2))
```

Let's go through this step by step:

- `a[0]` is `[-0.32963749, 3.4812, 1.7402]`, namely the 1st row
- `a[1]` is `[ 2.38905981, 1.00023, 8.65321]`, the 2nd row
- `a[0] - a[1]` is the elementwise difference: `[-2.7186973, 2.48097, -6.91301]`
- `(a[0]-a[1])**2` is the elementwise difference squared `[7.39131503, 6.15521214, 47.78970726]`
- Finally `np.sqrt(np.sum())` sums all the components together, and then take square root, hence `d` is  `7.831745298867902`

That said, numpy already has a build in function to compute this distance once you load the array:

```
d = np.linalg.norm(a[0]-a[1])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! So, if I want to calculate any number through python do I have to use numpy array(?)?

Comment: numpy has a lot of build in function to compute a lot of things, typically in a vectorized way, which leads to faster performance than vanilla python. Therefore I suggest you look into it :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try this:

```
import math

def calcDist(x1,y1,x2,y2):
     dist = math.sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)
     return dist       

distance = calcDist(x1, y1, x2, y2)
print(distance)
```

The function takes the 4 coordinates, and returns the distance between them using `math.sqrt`. Let me know if you have any other questions about how to possibly read in the variables. I would recommend reading in the lines, and using `line.split()` to get each variable.