# Sort an array of multi D points by distance to a reference point

Tags: python, numpy, sorting, multidimensional-array, distance

I have a reference point `p_ref` stored in a numpy array with a shape of (1024,), something like:

```
print(p_ref)
>>> array([ p1,  p2,  p3, ..., p_n])
```

I also have a numpy array `A_points` with a shape of (1024,5000) containing 5000 points, each having 1024 dimensions like `p_ref`. My problem: **I would like to sort the points in `A_points` by their (eucledian) distance to `p_ref`!**

How can I do this? I read about `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist` and `scipy.spatial.KDTree`, but they both weren't doing exactly what I wanted and when I tried to combine them I made a mess. Thanks!

---

For reference and consistency let's assume:

```
p_ref = np.array([0,1,2,3])
A_points = np.reshape(np.array([10,3,2,13,4,5,16,3,8,19,4,11]), (4,3))
```

Expected output:

```
array([[ 3,  2, 10],
       [ 4,  5, 13],
       [ 3,  8, 16],
       [ 4, 11, 19]])
```

Comment: Can you also add the expected output for the toy example? I would assume the output would just be a different row order of `A_points`.

Comment: @Divakar Sure, I added it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Updated on suggestions by the OP.

I hope I understand you correctly, but you can calculate the distance between two vectors by using [numpy.linalg.norm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401712/how-can-the-euclidean-distance-be-calculated-with-numpy).  Using this it should be as simple as:

```
A_sorted = sorted( A_points.T, key = lambda x: np.linalg.norm(x - p_ref ) )
A_sorted = np.reshape(A_sorted, (3,4)).T
```

Comment: Thanks, I like the simplicity of the answer, although some other method might be faster! For it to work though I have to transpose `A_points` and eventually reshape the answer, looking like this: `A_sorted = sorted( A_points.T, key = lambda x: np.linalg.norm(x - p_ref ) )`, 
`A_sorted = np.reshape(A_sorted, (3,4)).T`. I accept your post as an answer, but If you want edit it with as suggested, I also provided toy values in my initial question

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this -

```
A_points[:,np.linalg.norm(A_points-p_ref[:,None],axis=0).argsort()]
```

Another with `np.einsum` that should be more efficient than `np.linalg.norm` -

```
d = A_points-p_ref[:,None]
out = A_points[:,np.einsum('ij,ij->j',d,d).argsort()]
```

Further optimize to leverage fast matrix-multiplication to replace last step -

```
A_points[:,((A_points**2).sum(0)+(p_ref**2).sum()-2*p_ref.dot(A_points)).argsort()]
```

Comment: Thanks! The first suggestion is good, but for it to work I have to transpose `A_points` and get rid of `[:,None]`, eventually having `A_out = A_points.T[np.linalg.norm(A_points.T-p_ref,axis=1).argsort()]`. If you care, you can edit your answer. You can also test with these toy values, they agree with the dimension I have in my post: `p_ref = np.array([0,1,2,3])`, 
`A_points = np.reshape(np.array([10,3,2,13,4,5,16,3,8,19,4,11]), (4,3))`. The second suggestion has also an issue with the dimensions, but I made it work for `dim(A)=(4,4)`, if you want you can change it, too.

Comment: @NeStack Are you sure? Both seem to work just fine for me. What made you conclude that these are not working?

Comment: Thanks for the answers again! I just tested your snippets the way you present them on the toy values and they aren't making the desired calculation, although they are running without an error (take note that dim(p_ref)=n, dim(A_points)=(n,m), I also included the toy values in the question to make it clearer). Still, I only had to rotate variable to make them work, so +1.

Comment: @NeStack So, I think you meant to sort each row of `A_points`. That was the confusion. Code edited.