# Getting the Euclidean distance of X and Y in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I'm fairly new to python so I hope somebody can help me. we have two arrays X and Y

```
X=np.array([[ 5.43840675, -1.05259078, -0.21793506,  8.56686818, -2.58056957,
        -0.07310339, -0.31181501,  0.02696586],
       [ 5.72318296, -0.99665473, -0.14540062,  8.32051008, -3.36201189,
        -0.04897565, -0.34271698, -0.0339766 ]])

Y=np.array([[ 5.72318296, -0.99665473, -0.14540062,  8.32051008, -3.36201189,
        -0.04897565, -0.34271698, -0.0339766 ],
       [ 5.43840675, -1.05259078, -0.21793506,  8.56686818, -2.58056957,
        -0.07310339, -0.31181501,  0.02696586]])
```

I was interested in calculating Euclidean distance of two numpy arrays (X and Y). for example the distance between X[1], Y[0]
should be zero since there is no difference between those vectors.

```
X[1]=[ 5.72318296, -0.99665473, -0.14540062,  8.32051008, -3.36201189, -0.04897565, -0.34271698, -0.0339766 ] is equal to 
Y[0]=[ 5.72318296, -0.99665473, -0.14540062,  8.32051008, -3.36201189, -0.04897565, -0.34271698, -0.0339766 ]
```

I need to get this idea to work so if anyone can show me what I need to do to get this to work I would really appreciate it.

Comment: There is a very clear formula to calculate Euclidean distance. What did you try?

Comment: Does this help you? [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401712/how-can-the-euclidean-distance-be-calculated-with-numpy)

Comment: @ DeepSpace  clear formula did not help because I have vectors inside an array

Comment: @MisterNox thank you but it's not help

Answer (score 1):

based on the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) formula:

```
import math
x = [ 5.72318296, -0.99665473, -0.14540062,  8.32051008, -3.36201189, -0.04897565, -0.34271698, -0.0339766 ]
y = [ 5.72318296, -0.99665473, -0.14540062,  8.32051008, -3.36201189, -0.04897565, -0.34271698, -0.0339766 ]
Index = 0
sum = 0
while Index < len(x):
    sum += (x[Index] - y[Index]) ** 2
    Index += 1
print(math.sqrt(sum))
```

Comment: thank you but this is not what i want,  i have vectors inside an array not simple array !!!!!!!!! @pooya

Comment: just wrap this code in a function and call it for each pair of vectors.