# Find distance between two points in scatter plot

Tags: algorithm, cartesian

I want to find the distance between two points on a scatter plot. For clarification see the image: [Scatter Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2QGR.png)

The challenge is to identify the points using an algorithm (as I want to automate it as much as possible), the rest is just getting distance between coordinates.
I would appreciate if someone points me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the [euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance). If you are using python, the package NumPy, which is often used for data analysis, provides a method for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401712/how-can-the-euclidean-distance-be-calculated-with-numpy).

Comment: I know about euclidian distance, the main issue is recognizing the points. Alternatively I can get distance for each point and find minima. Would that work?

Comment: What do you mean be recognizing the points? Do you just have the graphic and not the actual data?

Comment: I do have the data, I meant identify the points using mathematics. I differentiated to see when the trend decreases. Thanks for help.

Comment: "identify the points using mathematics". What does that even mean? A point is just a pair (x, y) of two real numbers, or how is the data formatted?