# subtracting every element of a list from a previous element in a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary which has a 2D list (list of a list). This 2D list contains x and y coordinates [x,y] of a particle. Whenever the particle moves, its new coordinates are appended to this 2D list in a dictionary. I want to calculate the distance between every location and append the result to another list (can just be a normal list without dictionary). What I want is something like the following:

```
dist1 = sqrt((x1-x0)^2 + (y1-y0)^2)
dist2 = sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2)
.....
distN = sqrt((xN-xN-1)^2 + (yN-yN-1)^2)
```

but I am having issues in accessing elements of a list in a dictionary. I have a very long 2D list but you can use the below example to give me some suggestions.

```
c = {"coordinates":[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]}
for k, dk in c.items():
    for x in dk:
        print(x[0], x[1])
```

I can access one element in the dk at a time in a loop but how to get the previous one? There should be a nice way of doing it but I just don't know.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you as you say "want to calculate the distance between every location" or do you want to calculate the distance only between successive coordinates?

Comment: only successive coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it also works:

```
c = {"coordinates":[[1,2],[3,4],[15,6],[7,8]]}
l1 = []
for k, dk in c.items():
    for x in dk:
        l1.append(x)
print(l1)
dist = [math.sqrt((p1[0]-p0[0])**2 + (p1[1]-p0[1])**2) for p1,p0 in zip(l1,l1[1:]
```

as others suggested in this question, better way to get `l1` is to use the following command:

```
l1 = c["coordinates"]
dist = [math.sqrt((p1[0]-p0[0])**2 + (p1[1]-p0[1])**2) for p1,p0 in zip(l1,l1[1:]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a for loop (probably not the most efficient solution):

```
import numpy as np

c = {"coordinates":[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]}
coordinates = np.array(c['coordinates'])

distances = []
for i in range(1, len(coordinates)):
    distances.append(np.linalg.norm(coordinates[i-1] - coordinates[i]))
print(distances)
# [2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903]
```

I also used numpy and its `linalg.norm` function to calculate the distance ([How can the Euclidean distance be calculated with NumPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401712/how-can-the-euclidean-distance-be-calculated-with-numpy)), but you could ofcourse use your own function or calculation in case you'd want that.