# Vector Calculations in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vector, calculation

I have CSV file with Vector3 values exported from a C# program.
I would like to use vector operations (like calculating the distance etc.) in pandas.
As far as I have seen, there is no Vector3 type in pandas. `np.array` offers this kind of operations but it is not available in pandas.
What is the easiest way to accomplish vector calculations in a dataframe like data structure?
I would appreciate a detailed description starting with how to import the records from the CSV file as a vector type and ending with a calculation example.
The csv file has the following format:

```
aBin, bBin1, bBin2, bBin3, bBin4, ...
1, "(-1.6831280, 0.0000000, 2.4093440)", "(0.9445564, 0.0000000, 1.9509810)", "(-1.6831280, 0.0000000, 2.4093440)", "(0.9445564, 0.0000000, 1.9509810)" ...
2, "(-5.6848290, 0.0000000, 2.7744440)", "(0.6555564, 0.0000000, 7.2209800)", "(-3.6818280, 0.0000000, 2.5663330)", "(0.6445564, 0.0000000, 2.9509810)" ...
...
```

**Edit**
This CSV contains measurements of a program. There is a similar CSV (same shape) of another program and I want to calculate the distances between those two CSV (e.g. the distance between the value of `[aBin1][bBin1]` of the first CSV with `[aBin1][bBin1]` of the second CSV). Finally I want to sum this distances to a single value.

Comment: There are two closing parentheses in columns `bBin2` and `bBin4` is that a typo? You can start with `pd.read_csv("your_file.csv", skipinitialspace = True, index_col="aBin")`

Comment: What kind of calculation are you trying to achieve? Your question needs more focus

Comment: Is is right to calculate the distance between 1st row and 2nd row?

Comment: Thanks for your comments! Yes the two parentheses were typos. I have updated the description with more details about the needed calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# vector1.txt
aBin, bBin1, bBin2
1, "(-1.6831280, 0.0000000, 2.4093440)", "(0.9445564, 0.0000000, 1.9509810)"
2, "(-5.6848290, 0.0000000, 2.7744440)", "(0.6555564, 0.0000000, 7.2209800)"
```

```
# vector2.txt
aBin, bBin1, bBin2
1, "(-1.6831280, 1.0000000, 2.4093440)", "(0.9445564, 2.0000000, 1.9509810)"
2, "(-5.6848290, 3.0000000, 2.7744440)", "(0.6555564, 4.0000000, 7.2209800)"
```

First, I loaded two files with `file_to_dataframe` function.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def file_to_dataframe(fpath):
    # Function to change the format of file -> DataFrame
    # You can skip it if you can load the file as DataFrame
    with open(fpath, "r") as f:
        columns = f.readline().rstrip().split(', ')[1:]
        df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
        for line in f:
            row = [x.replace('"', '') for x in line.rstrip().split(', "')[1:]]
            df = df.append(pd.Series(row, index=columns), ignore_index=True)
    return df.applymap(lambda x: np.array(eval(x)))

# Read file
df1 = file_to_dataframe('data/vector1.txt')
df2 = file_to_dataframe('data/vector2.txt')
```

```
>>df1
                        bBin1                       bBin2
0  [-1.683128, 0.0, 2.409344]  [0.9445564, 0.0, 1.950981]
1  [-5.684829, 0.0, 2.774444]   [0.6555564, 0.0, 7.22098]
>>df2
                        bBin1                       bBin2
0  [-1.683128, 1.0, 2.409344]  [0.9445564, 2.0, 1.950981]
1  [-5.684829, 3.0, 2.774444]   [0.6555564, 4.0, 7.22098]
```

And I got dist with `np.linalg.norm` function with flatten data from dataframe.
and I made DataFrame with the result.

```py
def dist(x, y):
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401712/how-can-the-euclidean-distance-be-calculated-with-numpy
    return np.linalg.norm(x-y)


new_vals = [dist(x, y) for x, y in zip(df1.values.flat, df2.values.flat)]
df_dist = pd.DataFrame(np.array(new_vals).reshape(df1.shape), columns=df1.columns, )
```

```
>>df_dist
   bBin1  bBin2
0    1.0    2.0
1    3.0    4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the pandas functions `read_csv` and `applymap`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import ast

df1 = pd.read_csv(your_file_1, skipinitialspace = True, index_col="aBin").applymap(lambda x: np.array(ast.literal_eval(x)))
df2 = pd.read_csv(your_file_2, skipinitialspace = True, index_col="aBin").applymap(lambda x: np.array(ast.literal_eval(x)))

df_out = (df1-df2).applymap(np.linalg.norm)
print(df_out)
```

Note: `ast.literal_eval` converts your tuple-strings to actual tuples and is safer as `eval`

`df_out.sum()` will give you the sum for each column and `df_out.sum().sum()` the total sum.