# How to use numpy function to add polars dataframe column

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, 3d, python-polars

This is the continuation of my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75363356/16703234) 
User [glebcom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13469933/glebcom) helped me with transition of coordinates from a string to list of float64 values.
In the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1401828/16703234) I found 2 methods how to calculate distance between coordinates:

1. using formula numpy.linalg.norm(a-b)
2. using from scipy.spatial import distance:dst = distance.euclidean(a, b)
   How to apply one of these formulas to calculate the distance between corrdinates from column c and d from polars data frame

```
import polars as pl
from scipy.spatial import distance
import numpy as np
pl.Config.set_fmt_str_lengths(2000)
data={"a": ["782.83    7363.51    6293    40   PD","850.68    7513.1    6262.17    40   PD"], "b": ["795.88    7462.65    6293    40   PD","1061.64    7486.08    6124.85    40   PD"]}
df=pl.DataFrame(data)
df=df.with_columns([
    pl.col("a").str.replace_all(r" +", " ")\
        .str.split(" ").arr.slice(0,3)\
        .cast(pl.List(pl.Float64)).alias("c"),\
    pl.col("b").str.replace_all(r" +", " ")\
        .str.split(" ").arr.slice(0,3)\
        .cast(pl.List(pl.Float64)).alias("d")\
])
print(df)
```

My tries were

```py
df=df.with_columns(np.linalg.norm(pl.col("C")-pl.col("d")).alias("distance"))
or
df=df.with_columns(distance(pl.col("C"),pl.col("d")).alias("distance"))
```

but none of the above works.
Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Artur

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to call `numpy.linalg.norm` directly on your polars data frame. It expects a numpy array of shape (N, n) (where N is your number of points and n is your number of dimension, 3).

You can prepare the data your self, pass it to numpy and put back the results in polars.

First, calculate the difference between the coordinates of your two points, across all 3 dimensions:

```py
diffs = df.select(
    [
        (pl.col("c").arr.get(i) - pl.col("d").arr.get(i)).alias(f"diff_{i}")
        for i in range(3)
    ]
)
```

```
┌─────────┬────────┬────────┐
│ diff_0  ┆ diff_1 ┆ diff_2 │
│ ---     ┆ ---    ┆ ---    │
│ f64     ┆ f64    ┆ f64    │
╞═════════╪════════╪════════╡
│ -13.05  ┆ -99.14 ┆ 0.0    │
│ -210.96 ┆ 27.02  ┆ 137.32 │
└─────────┴────────┴────────┘
```

Then convert it to numpy and call the function:

```py
import numpy.linalg
distance=numpy.linalg.norm(diffs.to_numpy(), axis=1)
pl.Series(distance).alias("distance")
```

```
┌────────────┐
│ distance   │
│ ---        │
│ f64        │
╞════════════╡
│ 99.99521   │
│ 253.161973 │
└────────────┘
```

Alternatively you can calculate the euclidian product yourself:

```py
df.select(
    [
        (pl.col("c").arr.get(i) - pl.col("d").arr.get(i)).alias(f"diff_{i}") ** 2
        for i in range(3)
    ]
).sum(axis=1).sqrt()
```

```
┌────────────┐
│ distance   │
│ ---        │
│ f64        │
╞════════════╡
│ 99.99521   │
│ 253.161973 │
└────────────┘
```

ps: `scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean` won't work because it only works with one point at time which would make it very slow in polars.

Answer (score 1):

Solution with `np.linalg.norm` inside `map`

```py
def l2_norm(s: pl.Series) -> pl.Series:
    # 1) difference: c-d
    diff = s.struct.field("c").to_numpy() - s.struct.field("d").to_numpy()
    # 2) apply np.linalg.norm()
    return pl.Series(diff).apply(
        lambda x: np.linalg.norm(np.array(x))
    )

df.with_columns([
    pl.struct(["c", "d"]).map(l2_norm).alias("distance")
])
```

```
┌────────────┐
│ distance   │
│ ---        │
│ f64        │
╞════════════╡
│ 99.99521   │
│ 253.161973 │
└────────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's a pity one can't mark two answers as solutions.